# Diferença básica entre Abstract Factory e Factory?

Tags: design-pattern

Eu estava dando uma olhada no [Manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.patterns.php) e vi um exemplo de implementação do padrão `Factory`.

Exemplo:

```
class Exemplo
{
    // Método Factory parametrizado
    public static function factory($type)
    {
        if (include_once 'Drivers/' . $type . '.php') {
            $classname = 'Driver_' . $type;
            return new $classname;
        } else {
            throw new Exception ('Driver não encontrado');
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
// Carregar um driver MySQL
$mysql = Exemplo::factory('MySQL');

// Carregar um driver SQLite 
$sqlite = Exemplo::factory('SQLite');
```

No [PHP do Jeito Certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html), vi que,  através do `Factory`, *uma classe simplesmente cria o objeto que você gostaria de usar*.

Não tenho nenhum exemplo de `Abstract Factory`, porém já vi num curso que fiz. E isso me deixou confuso.

Gostaria de saber, de maneira mais simplificada possível, quais são as diferenças entre esses dois patterns (padrões).

Comment: [Seria legal você dar uma olhada aqui também](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). O conceito de interfaces é novo no PHP.

Comment: Na primeira frase desse artigo do manual tem uma afirmação falsa. _Interfaces de Objetos permite a criação de código que especifica quais métodos e **variáveis** uma classe deve implementar ..._ O PHP Não aceita declarar variáveis numa interface :\

Comment: Tem certeza disso? Veja o exemplo 4.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, aquilo é uma constante, e não uma variável. Constantes podem ser colocadas numa interface, variáveis não.

Comment: Talvez tenha [se referido a propriedades](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2756989/1314276). De qualquer forma, é uma afirmação infeliz. Pena que não a achei na documentação.

Comment: Na versão em inglês não falam em variáveis haha, uma interface define quais comportamentos serão implementados por uma classe ou seja uma interface não tem nenhum método concreto(não implementa nenhum comportamento) logo não faz sentido ter estado. Caso precise manter estado de algo, uma classe abstrata parece ser mais adequado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Se quiser ver com mais detalhes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101

Answer (score 8):

O nome do *pattern* até que é bastante significativo.

Basicamente, *Abstract Factory* é a técnica de usar um *factory* abstraindo o conhecimento da implementação concreta daquele *factory*.

Do mesmo jeito que um *factory* tem a capacidade de abstrair a implementação concrecta do tipo que ele entrega retornando por exemplo uma interface em vez de retornar uma classe, o padrão *abstract factory* determina uma interface de *factory* abstraindo a implementação concreta do próprio *factory* que é retornado para o consumidor do factory.

## Exemplo em pseudo-código

#### Factory

```
Factory factory = new Factory();
IObjeto objeto = factory.create();
```

#### Abstract Factory

```
IFactory factory = abstractFactory.create();
IObjeto objeto = factory.create();
```

Nestes exemplos, *IObjeto* e *IFactory* são declarações de interfaces e não de tipos. O tipo do objeto que de fato é obtido em cada um dos exemplos é "desconhecido" ou irrelevante para o consumidor.

A implementação concreta de *factory* que será obtida ao utilizar o *pattern Abstract Factory* vai depender então de decisões externas ao código consumidor do *factory*, e será determinada por exemplo por arquivo de configuração, observação de regras de negócio, injeção de dependência, etc.

Lembrando que eu falei em *interface* no sentido de um contrato. Apesar de declaração de interfaces ser um recurso básico bastante comum em linguagens que suportam orientação a objetos, não precisa necessariamente usar este tipo de declaração se não for demandado pela linguagem ou se houver jeito mais bacana.

Comment: Uma dúvida: no abstract factory, você primeiro fabrica a fábrica, que então é usada para fabricar o objeto? Seria uma fábrica de fábricas então?

Comment: @Piovezan Precisamente. É claro que a explicação poderia ser mais detalhada, com exemplos mais profundos de implementação... Mas a pergunta pediu a explicação simplificada, então é esta aí.