# Qual a diferença entre Simple Factory, Factory Method, Abstract Factory?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, factory

Quais são as principais diferenças entre esses padrões de projeto? Em qual situação um padrão pode ser melhor do que o outro?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Todos padrões costumam ser abusados. Só devem ser usados quando realmente é uma solução para um problema real.

Já vi fábricas sendo usadas onde não precisava, onde o código podia construir os objetos sem intermediários.

## Simple Factory

É interessante quando você não sabe bem qual é o tipo do objeto que será usado. Normalmente uma classe de fábrica é criada para gerenciar isso. Nela teria um método que retorna o objeto do tipo correto de acordo com algum critério. Há casos que este método pode até ser estático e dispensar instanciar alguma coisa só para consumir a fábrica. Dá até mesmo para fazer sem uma classe. Claro que cada caso tem vantagem e desvantagem.

Há casos que um método estático é criado em uma classe, possivelmente abstrata, que é a base das classes que serão usadas para fabricar o objeto.

Uma forma comum é a seleção ser feita por um `switch`, recebendo uma *string* ou algo externo. Costuma ser um erro quando recebe uma enumeração. Se você sabe em tempo de desenvolvimento o que passar, então instancie logo o que precisa. Claro que tem casos legítimos para seu uso, por exemplo a enumeração ter sido gerada por um dado externo.

```
public class PizzaFactory {
    public Pizza CreatePizza(String sabor) {
        if (sabor == "Portuguesa")
            return new Portuguesa();
        if (sabor == "Calabreza")
            return new Calabreza();
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Todos os sabores derivam de `Pizza`. Então onde precisa da `Pizza` chamaria assim:

```
PizzaFactory fabricaDePizza = new PizzaFactory()
Pizza pizza = fabricaDePizza.createPizza(textBoxPizza);
```

O texto pode vir de vários lugares, esse que coloquei é óbvio, mas provavelmente inadequado em aplicação real.

Há quem prefira fazer a classe estática, assim não precisa instanciar nada, só para criar o que realmente deseja.

Claro que isso tem um problema de manutenção. Se criar uma sabor novo tem que mexer na classe da fábrica para adicioná-lo. Isso não é o fim do mundo em grande parte das aplicações, mas é em algumas.

A solução é criar um mecanismo de registro das classes de sabores na classe de fábrica ou fazer reflexão em casos bem padronizados. O primeiro seria algo assim:

```
class static PizzaFactory {
    private Dictionary<string, Pizza> pizzas = new Dictionary<string, Pizza>();
    public static void registerPizza(String nome, Pizza pizza) => pizzas[nome] = pizza;
    public static Pizza createPizza(String nome) => pizzas[nome].createPizza();
}
```

Aí cada classe de sabor vai se registrar e ter uma forma de instanciar. A classe de fábrica não precisa conhecer cada um dos sabores.

```
class Portuguesa : Pizza {
    ...
    static Pizza() => PizzaFactory.registerPizza("Portuguesa", new Portuguesa());
    public override Pizza createPizza() => new Portuguesa();
    ...
}
```

Obviamente que este não é o código completo e mais robusto possível, mas no geral essa solução é adequada em vários casos.

## Method Factory

Este padrão é usado para o caso que precisa construir instâncias de um jeito específico, fazer algo a mais que a construção normalmente faria, ou seja, você não precisa ter ciência de como consumir a construção do objeto de uma forma específica. Obviamente você pode ter várias linhas de fabricação diferentes para uma mesma classe, permitindo flexibilidade.

Isso é feito através de subclasse. Note que cada subclasse pode ter sua própria implementação, não interessa para o consumidor desse padrão qual é o objeto e como ele foi construído, ele só quer o resultado.

Assim como o padrão anterior É uma forma de poder ter a possibilidade de construção de objetos novos sem conhecer todos os existentes. Uma manutenção que crie um tipo novo pode ser consumido sem que qualquer parte do código a não ser o novo tipo seja escrito.

Note que a classe a ser fabricada também não precisa ter ciência que ela terá uma fábrica.

```
public abstract class PizzaFactory {
    protected abstract Pizza Make();
    public Pizza GetPizza() => this.Make(); //este é o método de fábrica
}

public class PortuguesaFactory : PizzaFactory {
    protected override Pizza Make() {
        Portuguesa pizza = new Portuguesa();
        pizza.GetHam();
        pizza.GetPea();
        pizza.GetOnion();
        pizza.GetEgg();
        return (Pizza)pizza;
    }
}
```

Desta forma pode chamar uma pizza que já faz pega os ingredientes específicos sem ter que se preocupar com isso. Em outro sabor os ingredientes são outros, mas não é problema seu, a fábrica de cada um sabe o que fazer, basta chamar o `GetPizza()` que vale para todos sabores. Algo assim:

```
PizzaFactory fabrica = new PortuguesaFactory();
Pizza pizza = fabrica.getPizza();
```

Há algumas versões diferentes de como é o jeito correto de fazer. É comum as pessoas alegarem que o jeito que elas gostam é o correto. Sinceramente eu não sei qual é o correto quando há tantas fontes. Esta é uma forma de implementar que funciona.

## Abstract Factory

Essencialmente é uma fábrica de fábricas. Ele é usado quando temos uma matriz de itens que se relacionam e precisam de uma criação abstrata que atenda qualquer item. Ele permite criar diversas configurações com itens relacionados. Assim é possível montar novas opções de forma independente sem uma ter ciência da outra.

Neste exemplo mais complexo criamos sabores e tipos de pizzas diferentes:

```
public interface IPizzaIngredientFactory {
    public Massa createMassa();
    public Molho createMolho();
    public Queijo createQueijo();
    public Acessorios[] createAcessorios();
    public Carne createCarne();
}

public class PremiumPizzaIngredientFactory : IPizzaIngredientFactory {
    public Massa createMassa() => new MassaFinaCrocante();
    public Molho createMolho() => new MolhoTomateEspecial();
    public Queijo createQueijo() => new QueijoMussarela();

    public Acessorios[] createAcessorios() => new Acessorios { new MiniAzeitona(), new CebolaRoxa() };
    public Carne createCarne() => new CarneRalada();
}

public abstract class Pizza {
    public string Nome;
    protected IMassa Massa;
    protected IMolho Molho;
    protected IAcessorios[] Acessorios;
    protected IQueijo Queijo;
    protected ICarne Carne;
    public abstract void Prepare();
}

public class Calabreza : Pizza {
    IPizzaIngredientFactory ingredientFactory;
    public CheesePizza(IPizzaIngredientFactory ingredientFactory) ingredientFactory = ingredientFactory;
    public override void Prepare() {
        Massa = ingredientFactory.CreateMassa();
        Molho = ingredientFactory.CreateMolho();
        Queijo = ingredientFactory.CreateQueijo();
        Carne = ingredientFactory.CreateCarne();
    }
}

public class PremiumPizza {
    protected override Pizza CreatePizza(string sabor) {
        Pizza pizza;
        IPizzaIngredientFactory ingredientFactory = new PremiumPizzaIngredientFactory();
        switch (sabor) {
        case "Portuguesa":
            pizza = new Portuguesa(ingredientFactory);
            pizza.Nome = "Pizza Premium Portuguesa";
            break;
        case "Calabreza":
            pizza = new Calabreza(ingredientFactory);
            pizza.Nome = "Pizza Premium Calabreza";
            break;
        }
        return pizza;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Factories.cs).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. eu entendi o Simple Factory mas não consegui entender os outros dois, talvez porque tenha código faltando. Mas a minha dúvida era em saber mais quando um é apropriado do que o outro. Quando eu to programando eu tento isolar as instancias de objeto, criando factories, mas sempre faço a simple factory porque eu não consigo entender a motivação da factory method e abstract factory... então a minha dúvida era mais sobre as diferentes motivações do que como que as coda

Comment: Posso tentar melhorar, mas coloquei esses exemplos até para entender na prática quando é usado. De fato o último é mais difíceis de entender, o Method Factory é bem simples também, vou tentar por algo mais, mas é aquilo que está escrito, usa-se quando precisa construir o objeto de um jeito específico e não quer ficar repetindo todo código toda vez que deseja criá-lo. Talvez seja difícil entender porque ele é simples demais e todo mundo espera algo complicado. O Simple Factory é o mais fácil de usar, mas também o mais mal usado.

Comment: Quando a pessoa não entende onde é para aplicar, provavelmente significa que não é p/ aplicar. É a necessidade que deve fazer a procura pelo padrão, não o padrão procurar uma necessidade.

Comment: Eu partilho de uma opinião diferente. Eu acho que é aceitável a pessoa não entender onde é para aplicar um padrão porque eles são complexos e exigem um domínio profundo da orientação a objetos que demora a se adquirir. Então, a situação pode estar lá, mas ele não sabe que se pode aplicar um padrão naquela situação porque ele não domina o padrão ou a linguagem. Na minha visão, não é sempre que é aplicado um padrão quando lhe é conveniente. Mas, de qualquer maneira, é muito bom que tenhamos opiniões diferentes porque isso enriquece o fórum e incita nos outros leitores o pensamento e a crítica.

Answer (score 4):

> Esta resposta é uma junção dos artigos do Vinícius Thiengo sobre [Simple Factory](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-simple-factory), [Factory Method](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-factory-method) e [Abstract Factory](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-abstract-factory).

De forma geral todos os padrões Factory (Simple Factory, Factory Method, Abstract Factory) encapsulam a criação de objetos.

**Simple Factory**

Simple Factory permite interfaces para criar objetos sem expor a criação lógica para o cliente.

O Simple Factory é um bom ponto de início para separar a criação de objetos do seu uso, poucas classes são criadas e a estrutura do padrão é bem simples. Se o seu contexto permite isolar a maneira como objetos são criados e você tiver que lidar apenas com um tipo de objeto, o Simple Factory é uma excelente maneira de resolver o problema.

Apesar de simples, existem situações onde utilizar o padrão Simple Factory não ajuda muito. Um sinal bem claro de que o padrão não está sendo efetivo é quando a classe fábrica começa a crescer e ter vários métodos para criar os mesmos produtos de maneiras diferentes. Essa talvez seja uma boa hora para aplicar outros padrões fábrica.

**Factory Method**

Factory Method define uma interface para criar um objeto, mas deixa que subclasses decidam que classe instanciar.

Factory Method pode ser usado quando uma classe não pode antecipar a classe de objetos que criam ou quando a classe quer que suas subclasses especifiquem os objetos que criam. Pode ser utilizado também quando as classes delegam responsabilidade para uma dentre várias subclasses auxiliares, e você quer localizar o conhecimento de qual subclasse auxiliar que é a delegada.

**Abstract Factory**

Abstract Factory provê interface para criar famílias de objetos relacionados ou dependentes sem especificar suas classes concretas.

O Abstract Factory pode ser utilizado quando um sistema deve ser independente de como seus produtos são criados, compostos ou representados e o sistema deve ser configurado como um produto de uma família de múltiplos produtos. Pode ser utilizado também quando uma família de objetos for projetada para ser usada em conjunto, e você necessita garantir esta restrição e quando você quer fornecer uma biblioteca de classes e quer revelar somente suas interfaces, não suas implementações.

Vale lembrar que não há uma versão melhor do Factory, cada uma se encaixa de maneira mais otimizada em problemas específicos de projeto de software. E isso vale para qualquer padrão de projeto.

Referências:

- [Simple Factory](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-simple-factory)
- [Factory Method](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-factory-method)
- [Abstract Factory](http://www.thiengo.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-abstract-factory)