# Implementação dos padrões Abstract Factory, Factory Method e Adapter

Tags: php, design-pattern

Li a seguinte frase:

> AbstractFactory define uma interface para a criação de uma família de produtos relacionados ou dependente uns dos outros sem que você precise especificar explicitamente as classes.

Considere o seguinte adaptador:

**Adapter.php**

```
namespace Teste\Db;

use Teste\Db\Adapter\DbInterface;

class Adapter
{
    private $config = null;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function factory()
    {
        $db = $this->config['db'];

        $class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\Adapter\DbAdapter' . $db;

        return new $class($this->config);
    }
}
```

Repare que essa classe possui o método `factory` que retorna a instância de uma nova classe conforme o arquivo de configurações:

**Config.ini**

```
db = MySQL
dbname = fixeads
username = 'root'
passwd = 'root'
host = localhost
debug = true
```

Utilizei o padrão *Factory Method* por saber qual classe que deverá ser utilizada apenas no momento da execução do script.
Repare que no arquivo de configurações há uma definição:

```
db = MySQL
```

Com isso o adaptador irá gerar uma instância da classe `DbAdapterMySQL` (na verdade a classe é do tipo `DbInterface`, veja abaixo):

```
<?php

namespace Teste\Db\Adapter;

use Teste\Util\Iterator\Collection;

class DbAdapterMySQL extends \PDO implements DbInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$config['dbname']};host={$config['host']}";
        parent::__construct($dsn, $config['username'], $config['passwd']);

        $this->setAttribute(self::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, self::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function insert($table, array $fields)
    {
       //inserir
    }

    public function select($table, $cols = '*', $where = [])
    {
        //selecionar
    }

    public function getFields($table)
    {
        //descrição dos campos
    }
}
```

Repare que a classe implementa a interface `DbInterface`:

```
<?php

namespace Teste\Db\Adapter;

interface DbInterface
{
    public function __construct(array $config);
    public function select($table, $cols = '*', $where = null);
    public function insert($table, array $fields);
    public function getFields($table);
}
```

E para utilizar tudo faço o seguinte:

```
$config = parse_ini_file(sprintf(__DIR__ . '%sconfig.ini', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
$dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config);
Mapper::$defaultAdapter = $dbAdapter->factory();
```

Posso dizer que utilizei os padrões *Adapter*, *Factory Method* e *Abstract Factory* nas classes acima?

- O padrão *Adapter* porque utilizei a classe `DbAdapterMySQL` para contruir uma interface compatível com a aplicação, sendo assim quando mudar de MySQL para MSSQL tenho apenas que criar uma nova classe `DbAdapterMSSQL` e implementar os respectivos métodos.
- O padrão *Factory Method* porque utilizei o método `factory` da classe  `Adapter` para retornar uma instância da classe que deverá ser usada (em tempo de execução) de acordo com as configurações do projeto.
- E aqui é a minha dúvida, posso dizer que utilizei o padrão *Abstract Factory*? Uma vez que utilizei a interface `DbInterface` para a criação de uma família de produtos relacionados, que nesse caso é para manipulação do SGBD?

Se sim, então a classe `Adapter` juntamente com as classes `DbInterface` e `DbAdapterMySQL` são a implementação do padrão *Abstract Factory*?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101

Answer (score 2):

Olá, não sou perito em php, mas pude compreender bem sua questão.

Minha primeira observação é sobre você estar utilizando o **abstract factory**, na realidade não vejo você empregando o mesmo, pois como você citou:

> Uma vez que utilizei a interface DbInterface para a criação de uma família de produtos relacionados, que nesse caso é para manipulação do SGBD

Aqui podemos observar que você não está fornecendo a criação para toda  uma família de produtos. Na verdade você apenas está se encarregando de prover a instância de um único produto, no caso instâncias para a base de dados.

Poderíamos considerar uma família por exemplo se você tivesse algo do gênero:

```
<?php

 namespace Teste\Db\Adapter;

class Adapter
{
    private $config = null;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
       $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function factoryBancoRelacional()
    {
    }
    public function factoryBancoNaoRelacional()
    {
    }
}
```

Note a diferença, você tem uma classe responsável por lhe devolver diferentes tipos de bancos, que são incompatíveis entre si, porém pertencem a mesma família de **Gerenciadores de Banco de Dados**, diferente do modelo anterior onde você tem uma classe que vai sempre lhe devolver uma instância de um único tipo de produto, um banco relacional.

Com isso em mente, eu vejo que com a soma destes padrões você acabou no padrão estrutural **Bridge**.

Por quê desta minha visão?

No site [source making](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge) fica bem claro a definição deste padrão. Abaixo algumas algumas das regras que o definem:

> Adapter makes things work after they're designed; Bridge makes them work before they are.
>
> - Decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently.
> - Publish interface in an inheritance hierarchy, and bury implementation in its own inheritance hierarchy.
> - Beyond encapsulation, to insulation

E basicamente o que você fez foi aproveitar-se tanto do **[Adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter)**, uma vez que você está estruturando sua aplicação para que bancos "incompatíveis" entre si possam ser utilizados através de uma única perspectiva em seu código, quando do **[Bridge](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge)**, onde sua abstração Adapter, que fornece o factory para o banco de dados, pode variar de maneira independente, tanto quanto as implementações de DbInterface que executa os seus comandos na base.

Espero que está minha visão possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) você verá um exemplo bem legal do conceito de família dentro do abstract factory.