# O que fazer quando o argumento passado no construtor é inválido?

Tags: java, exceção, estilo-de-codificação, construtor

Estou fazendo um jogo de cartas em Java, e uma das classes se responsabiliza por iniciar a partida. No construtor, eu recebo o número de jogadores que vão participar. Estou fazendo a validação da quantidade de *players* no próprio construtor, mas como deve agir se o usuário informar um número abaixo ou acima da condição estabelecida pelo programa?

Devo lançar alguma exceção em específico e impedir a instanciação do objeto? Existe práticas recomendadas para situações assim?

Comment: Valide isso antes de passar pro construtor, e informe ao usuário q é inválido, possibilitando que ele informe novamente. Ficar lançando exceção não é solução pra nada, alias, é uma péssima prática. Exceções é pra se usar em "exceções", como o próprio nome diz.

Comment: @Articuno então eu devo fazer a validação como um método independente da classe que pretendo instanciar? Seria interessante ter uma classe somente para a validação dos dados?

Comment: Não sei, depende. Se forem muitas validações, seria um caso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A análise nunca é tão simples, tudo depende de contexto, mas no geral é isso mesmo, deve lançar uma exceção impedindo que o objeto seja construído. Não conseguir criar um objeto costuma ser um caso excepcional, o normal deveria ser criar o objeto sem problemas. Note que a exceção em geral é um erro de programação. Um teste deve fazer ela ser lançada e você deve corrigir.

Em alguns casos pode ser que [criar uma situação inválida com nulo seja interessante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), mas não é tão comum e só lançando a exceção pode fazer isto no construtor (um [Simple Factory](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) pode devolver o nulo). Pode ver que vários objetos quando não podem ser criados ficam como nulos e não geram exceção, então é uma solução que faz sentido. Só não abuse disto. Essa solução é melhor quando a linguagem ajuda evitar nulos, o que não é o caso do Java, o que não impediu a linguagem de adotar a solução várias vezes.

Que fique claro que um objeto em estado inválido não deve ser construído. A forma de impedir isso pode variar um pouco. Um nulo é um objeto inválido, mas não um objeto criado em estado inválido.

Também não digo que não possa fazer isso nunca, pode ter caso pertinente.

Particularmente eu usaria a validação como último recurso quando tudo falhou antes, eu tentaria não deixar um argumento errado ser passado. Estourar a validação durante a criação do objeto é excepcional porque o erro foi ter chamado o construtor de forma inválida.

Já vi alguns casos e tenho pensado em fazer cada vez mais um método estático utilitário que faça uma validação e só depois de passar por ele é que a criação do objeto é realizada, assim você já sabe que tudo funcionará. Só não pode deixar de validar no construtor porque nada exige que esse utilitário seja chamado antes do construtor, e seria até complicado manter estado indicando que foi validado, seria só uma facilidade.

Eu sei que a filosofia da comunidade Java é abusar de exceções (ou pelo menos era, isso tem mudado ela tem preferido usar *factories* e retornar um [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html)). Então só deixar a exceção não está errado, só não acho bom.

<strike>Eu preferia que tivesse um mecanismo diferente para indicar erro de programação, que eu acho que é o caso, mas como não tem, a exceção é interessante</strike> Agora tem.

Só não vai colocar um `try-catch` para tentar resolver quando for criar este objeto. Não que não tenha situação que não possa ser útil, mas é raro. Geralmente tem que impedir a criação errada antes.

Tudo pode quando faz sentido. Por isso que eu sempre digo que seguir receitas não dá certo, tem que entender porque está fazendo aquilo.

Dê uma olhada em [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Levando em consideração que seja do mesmo tipo, eu também verificaria antes de criar um objeto.

Comment: @Maniero Você então aconselharia criar uma classe responsável pela validação dos dados antes de serem passados para a classe que desejo instanciar?

Comment: @LucasDirani não sei se criar uma classe, editei para melhorar isto.

Comment: @Maniero Perfeito, valeu mesmo pela ajuda, era isso que estava procurando. Agradeço a todos também que se disponibilizaram para sanar minha dúvida! :)

Answer (score 7):

A classe deve ser responsável por evitar ser instanciada num estado não válido.

Por isso, no construtor, os valores passados devem ser verificados e uma excepção deve ser lançando caso sejam inválidos.

No entanto, como esse valor é fornecido pelo usuário ele deve também ser verificado antes de se tentar instanciar o objecto.
Note que **não deve** ser utilizado um bloco `try/catch` para isso.

Comment: Uma boa prática portanto seria verificar os dados do usuário em uma classe destinada somente a este teste específico?

Comment: A validação da entrada de dados tem de ser feita para evitar a excepção. Se é feita numa classe à parte ou não depende do tipo, tamanho ou complexidade da aplicação.

Comment: @ramaral de forma geral concordo com este comentário, mas se for algo bem bobo, descartável, aí qualquer coisa vale :)

Comment: @Maniero Está a referir-se a que nem sempre é necessário validar a entrada?

Comment: Tamanho da aplicação.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, lançar exceção é o recomendado.

Idealmente, um construtor nunca deve devolver um objeto mal-construído ou construído incorretamente. Se devido ao fato de os parâmetros não serem adequados, o construtor não puder construir o objeto, lance a exceção.

No caso, `IllegalArgumentException` é uma boa candidata a ser lançada:

```
public class PartidaDoJogo {

    // ...

    public PartidaDoJogo(int numeroDeJogadores) {
        if (numeroDeJogadores < 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O número mínimo de jogadores é 4.");
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Aliás, não apenas construtores, mas nenhum método deve aceitar parâmetros inválidos. Sempre que o seu método ou construtor receber um parâmetro inválido ou for de alguma outra forma utilizado de forma indevida, lance uma exceção. Isso faz com que o seu código fique mais robusto ao ter mais salvaguardas que impedem os seus objetos de entrar em estados inválidos, o que faz com que os sistemas fiquem mais fáceis de se projetar e de testar. Com isso, erros de programação se manifestarão imediatamente, possibilitando a sua correção e terão uma chance menor de bagunçar com as demais partes do sistema mesmo quando ocorrerem.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Realmente eu tinha encontrado em algumas fontes a sugestão do uso da IllegalArgumentException para casos assim. O pessoal aqui sugeriu também fazer a verificação dos dados antes de passar para a classe que quero instanciar, então penso que o ideal seja mesmo fazer essa checagem prévia e no Construtor se certificar com o uso da Exceção. O pensamento está correto?

Comment: @LucasDirani Sim, está correto.