# Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, construtor

Pense em uma classe grande, um cadastro completo de cliente por exemplo. Tem uma quantidade enorme de atributos nele. Muitos deles precisam ser inicializados na construção do objeto para o objeto ser válido, e de antemão não sabe se todos estão válidos ou se o uso conjunto deles torna o objeto válido. O objeto pode ser usado em diversos contextos da aplicação. Poderíamos fazer:

1. Um construtor com todos os parâmetros necessários e ele valida tudo e decide se conclui a construção ou não.
2. Um construtor só com o básico para criar o objeto e depois deixar colocar valor em outros atributos validando individualmente.

   Como deve proceder com a invalidade temporária?
3. Ter um método estático que valide tudo antes de chamar o construtor para saber que vai construir corretamente.
4. Criar um objeto temporário de um tipo definido para este propósito e usá-lo como base para criar o objeto definitivo, provavelmente com um construtor que aceite este objeto e saiba o que fazer.

   Este objeto aceitaria os atributos incrementalmente e poderia validar em determinado momento para poder ser usado no objeto real.
5. Alguma outra forma.

Eu imagino que todas podem ser úteis em alguma situação específica, ainda que algumas de forma bem rara e praticamente para contornar alguma outra deficiência.

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem e em que cenário escolher cada uma?

Referência: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101)

Comment: O que procura são as vantagens/desvantagens de aplicar cada uma das 5 abordagens a uma classe do tipo que refere e naquele cenário? Ou, pelo contrário, é algo mais genérico em que cada uma das 5 abordagens se aplicam ou podem aplicar a tipos/cenários diferentes, como a resposta do Victor Stafusa?

Comment: @ramaral o primeiro. Eu acho a resposta do Victor muito boa, mas ainda não sei se respondeu tangencialmente a pergunta. Diretamente não respondeu.

Comment: Notei a sua preocupação em definir um contexto, no entanto perguntei para ter a certeza.

Comment: @ramaral você está pretendendo dar uma resposta mais alinhada com a pergunta?

Comment: Pensei fazê-lo mas não consegui nada que considerasse suficiente para postar. A minha pouca experiência nesta área(sou apenas um curioso), apesar de dedicar algum tempo a pensar sobre estes assuntos, não me permite arrumar as minhas ideias de forma consistente e fundamentada para formular uma resposta.

Comment: Além do que é óbvio dizer em relação às hipóteses 1 e 2 apenas acrescentaria que optaria por uma classe tipo *factory* que permitisse construir o objecto de forma incremental. Cada um dos métodos factory retornaria uma interface cujo contracto permite usar o objecto num estado válido e receberia um objecto(interface) correspondente ao estado imediatamente anterior ao que irá construir. Não sei se isto se enquadra no que refere no ponto 4.

Comment: É claro que o uso de interfaces não garante que o objecto seja usado num estado inválido(é sempre possível fazer o cast para o objecto "total"). No entanto, fazer isso(o cast) será uma acção premeditada  e "quem" o fizer tem de ter consciência das consequências.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## TL;DR

Há várias alternativas possíveis para se reduzir a complexidade de criação de um objeto. Primeiramente deve-se verificar se a classe está bem arquitetada, respeitando-se o princípio da responsabilidade única e o da alta coesão. Os padrões de projeto *Façade*, *Strategy* e *State* podem ser muito úteis nesta tarefa, além de usar-se especialização de classes.

Em seguida, pode-se cogitar a utilização de injeção de dependências, *Service Locator* ou outra forma de inversão de controle pode ser uma saída. Caso isso não seja o suficiente, convém adotar-se sobrecargas de construtores, *Factory Method*, *Factory* ou *Prototype*. Caso isso não baste, pode-se partir para os padrões de projeto mais complexos *Abstract Factory* ou *Builder*.

Não existe receita de bolo para se realizar esse processo. Cada caso é um caso. Em determinados casos, alguns desses processos darão certos, outros não. Em outros casos, pode ser que aquele que deu certo no primeiro, não funcione, mas aquele que havia sido descartado, dessa vez seja o melhor. Há casos onde você terá que combinar diversas abordagens para ter um bom resultado e há casos onde existem várias abordagens possíveis igualmente satisfatórias. É necessário um certo tato e visão do todo para se perceber qual desses seria o melhor, e uma boa dose de experimentação também, além de aplicar-se refatorações e mudanças caso o projeto evolua de uma forma em que o que era bom antes deixe de ser agora.

## O [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) e a [alta coesão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))

Primeiro, se você tem uma classe com uma quantidade enorme de atributos, provavelmente ela está violando o **princípio da responsabilidade única** e tem baixa coesão.

O princípio da responsabilidade única diz que a classe deve ter, uma, somente uma e não mais do que uma responsabilidade. Ela deve servir para modelar exatamente um conceito no projeto.

Já a coesão é uma forma de avaliar o quanto que uma classe modela a sua responsabilidade. Uma classe tem alta coesão quando ela tem uma única responsabilidade bem definida e a modela completamente. Quanto mais alta a coesão, melhor.

Um exemplo onde o princípio da responsabilidade única é violada é naquela classe faz-tudo com um monte de métodos para mil finalidades diferentes. Nem precisa ser algo tão gritante assim, pois aquela classe que modela `Funcionario`, mas que tem dentro ela alguns dados de algo que seria de `Empresa` e também tem os métodos para validar o CPF e o número de celular também é uma violação do princípio da responsabilidade única.

Classes que são modeladas falhando-se em decompor-se os seus conceitos adequadamente também falham com o princípio da responsabilidade única e da alta coesão. Por exemplo:

```java
public class Funcionario {
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private LocalDate nascimento;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String pais;
    private String endereco;
    private String numeroEndereco;
    private String complemento;
    private int dddCelular;
    private int numeroCelular;
    private int dddTelefoneFixo;
    private int numeroTelefoneFixo;
    private int ramalTelefoneFixo;

    // Um construtor gigante e uma porrada de métodos aqui.
}
```

Observe que é possível decompor-se essa classe em classes menores: `Telefone`, `Endereco`, `Cidade`, `Estado`, `Pais`, podendo chegar-se a algo semelhante a isso:

```java
public class Funcionario {
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private LocalDate nascimento;
    private Endereco endereco;
    private List<Telefone> telefones;

    // Um construtor razoável com alguns métodos aqui.
}
```

Esse processo tem uma certa semelhança com o processo de normalização de banco de dados, embora seja algo ainda bem diferente. A ideia é a que ao usar conceitos de composição, agregação e associação, é possível extrair-se componentes relacionados em conceitos a parte, aumentando-se a coesão e caminhando-se em direção à responsabilidade única. Obviamente, esse processo altera a forma como a classe é instanciada.

Entretanto, embora ter uma responsabilidade única seja necessário para se atingir alta coesão, ainda assim não é suficiente. A classe deve também assumir a sua responsabilidade por completo, para evitar que essas recaiam em outras classes alheias.

Um exemplo onde há falha na coesão é quando começam a aparecer coisas assim:

```java
public class FuncionarioHelper {
    public void marcarFerias(Funcionario f) {
        // ...
    }

    public void obterSalario(Funcionario f) {
        // ...
    }

    public void cadastrarDependente(Funcionario f, Dependente d) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Esses métodos aí representam regras de negócio da classe `Funcionario`, e portanto, nela deveriam estar. O fato de lá não estarem, significa que a classe `Funcionario` provavelmente tem uma coesão baixa. O ideal seria fazer isso:

```java
public class Funcionario {

    // Tudo que já estava antes.

    public void marcarFerias() {
        // ...
    }

    public void obterSalario() {
        // ...
    }

    public void cadastrarDependente(Dependente d) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Isso daí também tende a melhorar o [**encapsulamento**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), vez que a classe (no caso `Funcionario`) terá bem menos necessidade de compartilhar e expôr seus dados internos. Isso daí também tem efeito direto em reduzir o [**acoplamento**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), que é uma forma de avaliar o quanto uma classe depende de outras. Quanto menor o acoplamento, melhor.

Em geral, classes que tenham nomes contendo palavras tais como `Utils`, `Helper`, `Manager`, entre outros, são indícios de que há problemas na coesão das classes. Em alguns casos, isso é inevitável porque não é possível adicionar-se métodos novos na classe desejada (por exemplo, uma classe `StringUtils` frequentemente têm um monte de métodos de coisas que gostaríamos que estivessem na classe `String`, mas que não temos como colocar lá por não podermos alterá-la).

Em linguagens como Ruby e JavaScript, em que é possível adicionar-se métodos a classes já existentes sem modificá-las diretamente (conceito esse denominado *mix-in*), este problema é sanado. Por exemplo:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    let r = "";
    for (let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
        r = this.charAt(x) + r;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Assim sendo, ao refatorar-se a classe, dividindo atributos lógicos relacionados em classes a parte, separados daqueles onde há uma menor relação, tende-se a obter classes que são muito mais simples de serem instanciadas e de serem reutilizadas e que têm um melhor encapsulamento, necessitando de menos parâmetros nos construtores. A forma de refatorar-se isso, por vezes nos leva ao padrão de projeto *façade*.

## O padrão de projeto [*Façade*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade)

Por vezes, uma classe representa um conjunto bem complexo de subsistemas. Neste caso convém dividi-la nesses subsistemas (ou mais frequentemente, integrar-se diversos subsistemas complexos em uma interface mais simples). Uma classe pode ser utilizada para agregar todos esses subcomponentes em um componente maior, de forma que a classe resultante seja uma **fachada** para todos esses sistemas (logo o nome desse padrão de projeto é *façade*). Para a instanciação, isso significa que:

- Cada um desses subsistemas poderia ser instanciado de forma independente, mas ao instanciá-los (ou de outra forma obter instâncias) no escopo do *façade*, a complexidade da criação deles é encapsulada.
- Cada um doss subcomponentes tem regras próprias e representam uma responsabilidade menor dentro de um sistema maior, e portanto ao separá-las, caminhamos em direção ao princípio da responsabilidade única, da alta coesão e também a um bom encapsulamento.

Um exemplo de um *façade* seria isso:

```java
public class Carro {
    private Roda frontalEsquerda;
    private Roda frontalDireita;
    private Roda traseiraEsquerda;
    private Roda traseiraDireita;
    private Cambio cambio;
    private Motor motor;
    private Volante volante;
    private Porta portaEsquerda;
    private Porta portaDireita;
    private Tanque tanqueCombustivel;
    private Radiador radiador;

    // ...
}
```

Observe que no caso acima, embora o `Carro` tenha diversos subcomponentes, quando ele for instanciado, será responsabilidade do construtor (ou de algum outro método de fabricação, tal como será descrito mais abaixo) prover-se implementações concretas de detalhes internos tais como o `tanqueCombustivel` ou o `cambio`.

Além disso, no padrão *façade*, o encapsulamento é melhorado, pois é esperado que tenha-se métodos assim:

```java
    public double getCapacidadeCombustivel() {
        return tanque.getCapacidadeCombustivel();
    }

    public double getNivelCombustivel() {
        return tanque.getNivelCombustivel();
    }

    public void abastecer(TipoCombustivel tipo, double litros) {
        if (!motor.isCombustivelAceito(tipo)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Este carro não deve ser abastecido com esse tipo de combustível.");
        }
        tanque.abastecer(tipo, litros);
    }

    public List<TipoCombustivel> getTiposCombustivelAceitos() {
        return motor.getTiposCombustivelAceitos();
    }
```

E não é esperado que tenha-se métodos assim:

```java
    public void setPortaDireita(Porta portaDireita) {
        this.portaDireita = portaDireita;
    }

    public void setNivelCombustivel(double nivel) {
        tanque.setNivelCombustivel(nivel);
    }

    public Motor getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }
```

Um caso disso mais próximo à realidade seria o de uma classe para fazer uma requisição HTTP para realizar download e/ou upload de alguma coisa. Ao invés de colocar tudo numa só classe gigantesca `RequisicaoHttp`, você teria uma classe para representar um cabeçalho, uma para representar o método HTTP, uma para representar o corpo da requisição, uma para representar o corpo da resposta, o código de status, a URL invocada, etc. Se você quiser algo que já trate da serialização/*marshalling* e desserialização/*unmarshalling* da requisição e da resposta em objetos (ao invés de strings ou sequências de bytes brutas), vai modelar esses comportamentos em classes a parte também. É exatamente esse o caso do [*namespace* `System.Net.Http` do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx).

Entretanto, pode ser que esse tipo de refatoração não seja suficiente ou não seja possível. Ainda assim, existem alternativas que podem ser utilizadas conforme listadas abaixo.

## Especialização de classes

Vamos supor que você tenha uma classe `Funcionario` que serve para modelar médicos, professores, advogados, contadores, etc e existam atributos que só tem sentido em determinados casos. Nessa situação, convém criar classes especializadas para cada um desses casos específicos cada uma com seus atributos específicos, de forma que nenhuma classe venha a ter atributos que são usados só em determinados casos. Isso tornaria então a classe `Funcionario` em uma superclasse ou uma interface.

## Os padrões de projeto [*Strategy*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy) e [*State*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/State)

Por vezes ocorre de uma classe ter um monte de atributos porque ela modela um objeto complexo que pode ter uma série de comportamentos diferentes, o que por si só já é uma violação do princípio da responsabilidade única.

A solução nesses casos é mover-se os comportamentos para classes a parte. Por exemplo, ao invés disso:

```js
function Peca(tabuleiro, cor, x, y, tipo) {

    function verificarMovimentoRei() {
        // ...
    }

    function verificarMovimentoDama() {
        // ...
    }

    function verificarMovimentoBispo() {
        // ...
    }

    this.mover = function() {
        if (tipo === "Rei") {
            if (verificarMovimentoRei()) // ...
            // ...
        } else if (tipo === "Dama") {
            if (verificarMovimentoDama()) // ...
            // ...
        } else if (tipo === "Bispo") {
            if (verificarMovimentoBispo()) // ...
            // ...
        } else //...
        // ...
    }
}
```

É melhor fazer isso:

```js
function Rei() {
    function verificarMovimento(tabuleiro, cor, x, y) {
        // ...
    }
}

function Dama() {
    function verificarMovimento(tabuleiro, cor, x, y) {
        // ...
    }
}

function Bispo() {
    function verificarMovimento(tabuleiro, cor, x, y) {
        // ...
    }
}

function Peca(tabuleiro, cor, x, y, tipo) {

    this.mover = function() {
        if (tipo.verificarMovimento(tabuleiro, cor, x, y) // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Isso tende a facilitar a criação dos objetos porque primeiro que melhora a coesão e a questão da responsabilidade única, mas também porque muitas vezes há atributos que só tem sentido de serem usados em comportamentos específicos.

Às vezes, um objeto pode mudar de comportamento (imagine o peão que é promovido e se transforma em uma outra peça). Nesse caso o padrão é o *State*, que é o irmão gêmeo do *Strategy*, mas quando o comportamento é mutável.

Note que uma classe pode implementar vários comportamentos distintos, cada qual no seu *Strategy* ou *State*.

## Sobrecarga de construtores

Lembre-se que em muitas linguagens de programação (nem todas), os construtores podem ser sobrecarregados. Por vezes, apesar de o objeto até poder ter um grande número de atributos e modelar regras complexas, há apenas um pequeno número de situações onde é válido criar-se um deles a partir do nada e cada uma dessas dependem de conjuntos de parâmetros razoavelmente simples, talvez independente uns dos outros. Nesse caso, uma possível saída seria a de ter múltiplos construtores, cada qual trabalhando com um conjunto de parâmetros diferente. Lembre-se também que um construtor pode chamar outro.

## O padrão de projeto [*Factory Method*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method)

Entretanto, nem sempre dá para modelar todos os casos em que o objeto é fabricado por meio de múltiplos construtores, ainda mais considerando que, devido ao fato de todos os construtores de uma classe terem o mesmo nome em muitas linguagens de programação, pode acontecer de haver casos completamente diferentes que trabalham com parâmetros do mesmo tipo. Dessa forma, trabalhar com múltiplos métodos de fabricação ao invés de múltiplos construtores pode ser a saída.

- É possível colocar-se o construtor como privado ou interno e então acrescentar-se métodos estáticos para fabricar as instâncias, cada um desses cobrindo um caso específico. É isso que acontece com a [classe `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), por exemplo.
- É possível que a classe tenha um comportamento modelado por uma interface (ou que você a refatore para atingir isso). Então, você pode definir métodos estáticos de fábrica que produzem instâncias de diversas formas podem ser disponibilizados. Exemplos reais são a [classe `javax.swing.BorderFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html) e os [métodos `of(...)` da interface `java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (acrescentados no Java 9).

## O padrão de projeto [*Prototype*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype)

Por vezes, a complexidade da criação de um objeto está em criar cópias de um objeto já existente com propriedades um pouco diferentes. O objeto base é algo simples, mas precisamos de vários objetos derivados. Uma implementação direta passando um caminhão de parâmetros no construtor nos levaria a algo assim:

```java
Personagem modelo = ...;
Personagem novo = new Personagem(
        modelo.getClasse(),
        modelo.getForca(),
        modelo.getInteligencia(),
        modelo.getPoder(),
        novaVelocidade, // Esse daqui não é copiado do modelo.
        modelo.getHP(),
        modelo.getMP());
```

Observe que ficar copiando os atributos de um objeto para outro sendo os dois da mesma classe e estando esse código em uma classe diversa é uma coisa que ocasiona um alto acoplamento e uma baixa coesão. Assim sendo, é melhor que o objeto disponibilize um método que retorne um outro objeto semelhante a ser modificado (ou mesmo já modificado), de forma que a complexidade da criação de objetos derivados se reduz. Por exemplo, vamos supor que a classe `Personagem` tenha métodos assim:

```java
public Personagem comForca(int novaForca) {
    return new Personagem(
            this.classe, novaForca, this.inteligencia, this.velocidade, this.hp, this.mp);
}

public Personagem comVelocidade(int novaVelocidade) {
    return new Personagem(
            this.classe, this.forca, this.inteligencia, novaVelocidade, this.hp, this.mp);
}
```

Podemos então usar assim:

```java
Personagem modelo = ...;
Personagem novo = modelo.comVelocidade(novaVelocidade);
```

Uma outra possibilidade seria fazer apenas isso:

```java
// Na classe Personagem:

public Personagem clone() {
    return new Personagem(/* Aquele montão de parâmetros... */);
}
```

```java
// No código que usa a classe:

Personagem modelo = ...;
Personagem novo = modelo.clone();
novo.setVelocidade(novaVelocidade);
```

A segunda abordagem é mais simples e mais flexível, porém a primeira é mais robusta.

## O padrão de projeto *Factory*

O *Factory* é um objeto cujo propósito é o de criar um determinado outro objeto. Deve ser fácil de se obter uma instância desses objetos (via construtor, *Factory Method*, [*Singleton*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) ou coisa semelhante).

Um exemplo real é a classe [`javax.swing.PopupFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/PopupFactory.html) que contém dois métodos diferentes para se criar popups.

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que é possível configurar-se a *Factory* antes de chamar-se os métodos de criação de instâncias, que inclusive podem ser chamados múltiplas vezes com a mesma instância da *Factory*.

## O padrão de projeto [*Abstract Factory*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Factory)

Um tipo especial de *factory* é aquela que permite múltiplas implementações distintas. Esse é o padrão de projeto *Abstract Factory*, onde a *factory* é definida por uma classe abstrata ou interface e é possível criar-se várias instâncias especializadas, cada qual construindo o objeto em questão do seu jeito. Frequentemente, nesses casos, o objeto em questão a ser produzido também é especificado por uma interface ou classe abstrata.

## O padrão de projeto [*Builder*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder)

Já o *Builder* é para usar em circunstâncias onde a criação é mais complicada, onde cada método configura um aspecto do objeto a ser produzido. Por exemplo:

```java
 ServidorHttp s = new ServidorHttpBuilder()
         .porta(1234)
         .baseUrl("http://www.example.com")
         .staticFileLocation("/public")
         .addFilter(new AccessControlFilter())
         .addFilter(new LoginFilter())
         .addServices(services)
         .build();
```

No caso, cada método do *Builder* com exceção do último (o `build()`) pode retornar tanto o próprio *Builder* (ou seja, retorna `this`, `self`, `Me` ou o equivalente de acordo com a linguagem de programação), ou então retorna uma nova instância do *Builder*.

Isso ainda tem a desvantagem de não garantir que todos os métodos do *Builder* que deveriam ser chamados são de fato chamados, nem de se certificar que nenhum deles é chamado duas vezes, e nem de garantir que eles sejam chamados na ordem correta (pode existir casos onde isso é importante). A solução nesse caso seria fazer o `ServidorHttpBuilder` ter apenas o método `porta` que retorna um `ServidorHttpBuilder2` que tem apenas o método `baseUrl` que retorna um `ServidorHttpBuilder3` que tem apenas o método `staticFileLocation`, etc. Essa abordagem garante que o método final `build()` só poderá ser chamado se todos os métodos que tiverem que ser chamados tiverem sido, que nenhum tenha sido chamado duas vezes e que eles sejam chamados na ordem correta, caso contrário, um erro de compilação ocorre. Entretanto, normalmente essa abordagem acrescenta bastante complexidade e um número excessivo de novas classes, sendo viável em poucos casos.

## [Inversão de controle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Frequentemente a dificuldade de instanciar-se uma classe, está em fornecer-lhe outros objetos que ela precisa para trabalhar, ou seja as suas **dependências**.

A ideia é livrar a classe que quer utilizar a classe a ser instanciada (classe cliente) de localizar todas as dependências e colocá-las na classe a ser instanciada. Observe que nesse caso, os padrões anteriores ajudam pouco, pois nenhum deles livrará a classe cliente deste trabalho, apenas o tornará mais fácil.

Assim sendo, uma abordagem a ser usada para fornecer as dependências adequadas a um objeto, livrando as classes que desejam utilizá-lo de ter que saber como encontrá-las é necessária. O nome disso é **Inversão de controle**.

### [Injeção de dependências](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Uma forma de se ter inversão de controle é delegar essa complexidade a um framework. O framework é configurado por meio de anotações, XML, JSON, convenções de código ou qualquer outra coisa de forma a saber quais são os pontos de injeção de dependências das classes. Esse pontos podem ser parâmetros no construtor, setters ou atributos soltos que serão preenchidos via reflection. Dessa forma, o código que deseja obter uma instância da classe, pede uma ao framework e o framework é o responsável por localizar todas as dependências e injetá-las, livrando o código que deseja apenas utilizar o objeto de ter que se preocupar com isso. O EJB, o CDI e o Spring são exemplos bem conhecidos de frameworks de injeção de dependência. Por exemplo, na classe a ser instanciada, coloca-se isso:

```java
public class Refeicao {
    private Fruta frutaSaborosa;
    private Fruta frutaDoce;

    public Refeicao (
            @Inject @Qualifier("saborosa") Fruta frutaSaborosa,
            @Inject @Qualifier("doce") Fruta frutaDoce)
    {
        this.frutaSaborosa = frutaSaborosa;
        this.frutaDoce = frutaDoce;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Na configuração do framework, coloca-se isso:

```xml
<bean id="saborosa" class="com.example.frutas.Morango"/>
<bean id="doce" class="com.example.frutas.Abacaxi"/>
```

Assim, quando o framework for instanciar a classe `Refeicao`, ele já vai automaticamente encontrar que `Morango` é a fruta saborosa e que `Abacaxi` é a fruta doce.

### O padrão de projeto [*Service Locator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)

A injeção de dependências é a forma mais comum de inversão de controle, mas não é a única. Uma outra forma popular é o padrão de projeto *Service Locator*. Neste padrão, há um objeto (o *Service Locator*) que é o responsável central por fornecer implementações de diversos objetos. Assim sendo, o objeto a ser instanciado pede ao *Service Locator* pela implementação de cada uma de suas dependências. A pesquisa no *Service Locator* pode ser feita por nome, por interface da qual se deseja alguma implementação ou por algum outro critério.

Por exemplo:

```java
public class Refeicao {
    private Fruta frutaSaborosa;
    private Fruta frutaDoce;

    public Refeicao() {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocator.getInstance();
        this.frutaSaborosa = (Fruta) locator.find("saborosa");
        this.frutaDoce = (Fruta) locator.find("doce");
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Conclusão

Há várias alternativas possíveis para se reduzir a complexidade de criação de um objeto. Primeiramente deve-se verificar se a classe está bem arquitetada, respeitando-se o princípio da responsabilidade única e o da alta coesão. Os padrões de projeto *Façade*, *Strategy* e *State* podem ser muito úteis nesta tarefa, além de usar-se especialização de classes.

Em seguida, pode-se cogitar a utilização de injeção de dependências, *Service Locator* ou outra forma de inversão de controle pode ser uma saída. Caso isso não seja o suficiente, convém adotar-se sobrecargas de construtores, *Factory Method*, *Factory* ou *Prototype*. Caso isso não baste, pode-se partir para os padrões de projeto mais complexos *Abstract Factory* ou *Builder*.

Answer (score 7):

A resposta do Victor já fala em tudo conteúdo eu gostaria de dar uma resposta bem mais simples.

Normalmente você tem uma e só uma forma de construir um objeto. Essa forma é a seguinte:

```
Object objecto = new Object();
```

E pronto, é isso. Todos os objectos são direta ou indiretamente construídos dessa forma e não tem nem outra opção. Mesmo que você opte por construir um objeto através de reflexão, você terá sempre que chamar o construtor com reflexão.

Os construtores devem garantir, na máxima extensão possível, que um objeto seja criado de forma válida e pronto a usar.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941943/1698682)

Dito doutra forma, deverá ser possível chamar qualquer método de instância sem que ele tenha problemas devido ao objeto não ter sido inicializado corretamente.

---

Passando pelas várias soluções por si propostas:

> Um construtor com todos os parâmetros necessários e ele valida tudo e
>   decide se conclui a construção ou não.

Esse é exatamente a técnica que deve ser seguida na maior parte dos casos, conforme já mencionei.

> Um construtor só com o básico para criar o objeto e depois deixar
>   colocar valor em outros atributos validando individualmente.
>
> Como deve proceder com a invalidade temporária?

Eu diria que isto depende muito da utilidade do objeto e até mesmo das convenções que você está a seguir com os seus colegas para o seu projeto atual! Muitas vezes eu faço um DTO na mão sem parâmetros no construtor e uso o inicializador.

Se isso é correto ou não eu diria que é uma questão filosófica. Pessoalmente eu diria que se o código funciona como esperado e que está tudo certo. Eventualmente poderá ter mais problemas com dados inconsistentes, mas pode sempre resolver verificando no lugar...

> Ter um método estático que valide tudo antes de chamar o construtor
>   para saber que vai construir corretamente.

Este também acontece, talvez um pouco menos frequentemente. Há alguns exemplos bem clássicos em `C#`, ora veja.

```
Tuple.Create(1, "a", 1.0);
File.OpenText("abc.txt"); //retorna um StreamReader
```

Nenhum desses métodos é estritamente necessário uma vez que você ainda pode construir esses objetos com o `new`. Mas eles são métodos de utilidade.

```
Tuple.Create(1, "a", 1.0); // = new Tuple<int, string, double>(1, "a", 1.0);
```

Outras vezes, você não tem mesmo outras opções e só pode construir objetos usando métodos estáticos. Isto acontece especialmente se você quiser esconder detalhes de implementação nas suas APIs, mantendo as classes que implementam a funcionalidade fechadas.

> Criar um objeto temporário de um tipo definido para este propósito e
>   usá-lo como base para criar o objeto definitivo, provavelmente com um
>   construtor que aceite este objeto e saiba o que fazer.
>
> Este objeto aceitaria os atributos incrementalmente e poderia validar
>   em determinado momento para poder ser usado no objeto real.

Este é bem clássico no Javascript e é conhecido pelo nome *Prototype*. Veja a resposta do Victor uma vez que acho que não preciso adicionar mais nada sobre o assunto.

> Alguma outra forma.

Bom, como eu disse anteriormente você tem só uma forma de construir um objeto. Usando o `new` e o construtor. Mas isso não quer dizer que resolva todos os seus problemas.

Haverá situações onde você tem que trabalhar sobre uma unidade lógica. E você terá eventualmente vários tipos de objetos cada qual trabalham sobre uma parte dessa unidade lógica.

Para entender melhor, imagine o seguinte cenário. Você tem um programa que trabalha com carros e motos. E tem as seguintes classes:

```
RodaMoto, MotorMoto, GuiadorMoto,
RodaCarro, MotorCarro, GuiadorCarro
```

Há padrões de desenho, que ajudam a agrupar os objetos por unidade lógica. Ou seja, que sabem como decidir que objeto usar em determinada situação. Por outras palavras, esses padrões podem ajudá-lo a agrupar todos os componentes respetivos à moto e todos os componentes respetivos ao carro.

E também o podem ajudar a decidir qual componente usar. Se você fornecer uma moto, ele decidirá usar os componentes da moto.

Mais uma vez, para mais detalhes veja a resposta do Victor. (*Abstract factory*, *factory*, *factory method*...)

Answer (score 3):

De tempos a tempos venho a esta pergunta para uma nova tentativa de construir uma resposta.
Em todos elas sempre me deparei com o problema de conseguir encontrar uma forma de abranger todos os aspectos que a pergunta determina.

Uma das tentativas era assim:

> No cenário que apresenta, as abordagens 1 e 3 não me parecem aplicáveis e a 2 e 4, apesar de poderem ser aplicáveis, transferem a responsabilidade da validação do objecto para o código cliente.
>
> Assim, apenas vou dizer o óbvio em relação a cada uma delas.
>
> **1 - Um construtor com todos os parâmetros necessários e ele valida tudo e decide se conclui a construção ou não.**
>
> - Garante que obtém um objecto válido.
>     É necessário dispor de todos os parâmetros necessários antes de o poder construir.
>
> **2 - Um construtor só com o básico para criar o objeto e depois deixar colocar valor em outros atributos validando individualmente.**
>
> - Possibilita dispor do objecto de imediato.
>     O código cliente terá de verificar, em cada momento de o usar, se o objecto está num estado válido para o uso em questão.
>
> **3 - Ter um método estático que valide tudo antes de chamar o construtor para saber que vai construir corretamente.**
>
> - Garante que obtém um objecto válido.
>     É necessário dispor de todas as informações necessários.
>     Permite adaptar a forma/tipo da informação disponível à forma/tipo requerida pelo construtor.
>
> **4 - Criar um objeto temporário de um tipo definido para este propósito e usá-lo como base para criar o objeto definitivo, provavelmente com um construtor que aceite este objeto e saiba o que fazer.**
>
> - Não sei se está a referir-se a um objecto tipo *factory* que permita construir o objecto de forma incremental. Cada um dos métodos *factory* retornaria uma interface cujo contracto permite usar o objecto num estado válido para um determinado contexto. Cada método receberia um objecto(interface) correspondente ao estado imediatamente anterior ao que irá construir.
> - Permite obter um objecto válido para um determinado contexto.
>     Não garante que o objecto seja usado num estado inválido.

A resposta descreve vantagens e desvantagens, mas porventura existirão outra(o)s. Não exemplifica possíveis cenários de utilização, mas alguns podem ser inferidos.

A pergunta define claramente o seu contexto/domínio e os seus limites. No entanto não consigo construir uma resposta que inequivocamente responda a todas as exigências requeridas.
Não podendo, para construir uma resposta, usar o método descrito no ponto 1, já que não tenho todo o conhecimento necessário, optei por usar o método descrito no ponto 2 e assim, pelo menos, conseguiria construir uma.

A resposta seria válida?  Não sei, talvez.
A informação nela pode ser suficiente para que um determinado leitor a possa considerar válida no seu contexto. Um outro leitor pode, em função de outras vantagens/desvantagens que conheça, vir aqui editá-la, de forma a torná-la válida no seu cenário.
Outros há que tomarão a resposta como completamente válida e terão dissabores no futuro.

Uma forma que permitiria eu ter dado uma resposta completa seria a pergunta ter limites mais estreitos.
Uma solução seria dividir a pergunta em várias, sendo nesse caso necessário menos quantidade de conhecimento para responder a cada uma.

O cenário(a utilização do objecto Cliente) descrito na pergunta sofre do mesmo problema: o seu contexto/domínio tem limites demasiado amplos para que a resposta(o objecto Cliente) possa inequivocamente satisfazer todas as exigências.

A solução será, como para a pergunta, dividir o cenário em vários contextos mais limitados.
Em cada um deles será utilizado um Tipo Cliente diferente com apenas os membros necessários nesse contexto. As características e invariâncias desse tipo serão aquelas que são conhecidas nesse contexto.

Poderá assim ser usado o método 1, que é o único que garante obter um objecto válido.

Comment: Esclarecendo, os itens 2 e 4 não transfere a validação para o cliente, a classe do objeto ainda seria responsável pela validação, só que não ocorreria tudo no início, no 2 não aceitaria dados inválidos, e isto tem um problemas, mas não vou falar aqui, e no 4 poderia ocorrer da mesma forma, ou pelo menos manter um *status* em cada mudança de propriedade, mas provavelmente o ideal seria uma validação única no final, e só com o *status* de validado é que poderia transferir para o objeto principal, neste caso poderia exigir o cliente chamar o método validador, ...

Comment: ...mas talvez a passagem do objeto temporário para para principal ele mesmo se encarregasse de fazer a validação sem exigir nada do cliente, o que talvez não resolva o problema de vez, mas isto é outro aspecto. E Acredito que na 4 está falando do `Builder` e não `Factory`, o `Factory Method` seria o 3. Ou eu que estou enganado? Acho que uma resposta incompleta é melhor que nenhuma resposta ou errada. A completa é melhor, mas a incompleta é válida. Claro que boa parte dela é quase um meta :)

Comment: E o principal não acrescentou muito, mas ajuda ver melhor o problema e mostra que o que postei não deu para entender bem como eu implementaria, pelo menos nos itens 2 e 4. Verei o que posso fazer para melhorar a capacidade de ser melhor respondido sem criar problemas novos.

Comment: Parece que entendi mal o cenário que descreveu, Eu entendi como sendo uma aplicação com vários módulos(p.ex. Orçamentação, Encomendas, ...) e cada modulo usaria a mesma classe Cliente. Em alguns deles o Cliente até nunca chegaria a ser usado "completo". De facto o que refiro no 4 é um Builder.

Comment: *"Claro que boa parte dela é quase um meta"* - Achei interessante fazer a analogia entre a dificuldade de responder à pergunta e a dificuldade de usar o objecto Cliente, pelo menos da forma como entendi o cenário.

Comment: Entendeu certo o cenário, acho que só a questão de que a classe cliente ou o temporário dela seria responsável por toda validação, como todo objeto deveria ser.

Comment: "(...)que a classe cliente ou o temporário dela seria responsável por toda validação(..)" - quanto a isso não tenho nenhuma dúvida. Não veja o texto da "tentativa" como sendo uma resposta. Ela nada acrescenta porque não era essa a intenção, Ela foi incluída apenas para ajudar a construir a analogia e justificar a opção pela separação/divisão em vários contextos menores. É claro que isso apenas responde a uma parte da pergunta(ponto 5).

Comment: O trecho `O código cliente terá de verificar, em cada momento de o usar` me fez pensar que entendeu que a validação teria que ser feito pelo código consumidor, esclarecido então.

Comment: Não veja aquilo como uma resposta. Eu sei que a intenção era que o AR pegasse em cada um dos pontos e explicasse como implementaria, quais a dificuldades e eventuais problemas. Como eu concordo totalmente quando diz: *"Eu imagino que todas podem ser úteis em alguma situação específica, ainda que algumas de forma bem rara e praticamente para contornar alguma outra deficiência."*, preferi focar-me no ponto 5. Talvez não tenha sido feliz com a analogia.