# Tirar um atributo de uma Classe

Tags: android

Minha classe pede como parâmetro um contexto (por exemplo: `MainActivity`). Eu consigo deixar sem o contexto? apenas passando como parâmetro a query...

Está desta forma:

```
public HttpTask(Context context, String query)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        mHttpRequest = new HttpRequest(context, "https://services-dev.redetendencia.com.br", query);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        result = mHttpRequest.buscarSql();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        try {
            ((Interface) context).onQueryTaskExecute(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface Interface {
        void onQueryTaskExecute(String result) throws JSONException;
    }
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/64969

Answer (score 0):

Você pode permitir que a classe seja instanciada sem requerer o context criando uma outra construtora com somente o String query como parâmetro. Agora você não poderá utilizar nenhum método interno que exija context.