# Dúvida sobre o cálculo do preço

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

A minha dúvida pode parecer simples para alguém, mas para mim está meio que me matando pois estou tentando achar o erro e não estou conseguindo.

A princípio, eu sei muito pouco sobre a programação orientada a objeto em Java, já que a maioria das vezes no meu curso eu só utilizo C ou C++. Então decidi pegar um curso em Java para aprender um pouco mais, mas pelo visto é muito diferente do que eu sei fazer.

Então vou passar a questão aqui e mais o meu código que eu não estou conseguindo calcular o preço total.

> Crie uma classe `Pizza` que possua o método `adicionaIngrediente()` que recebe uma `String` com o ingrediente a ser adicionado. Essa classe também deve possuir o método `getPreco()` que calcula da seguinte forma: 2 ingredientes ou menos custam 15 reais, de 3 a 5 ingredientes custam 20 reais e mais de 5 ingredientes custa 23 reais.
>
> É preciso contabilizar os ingredientes gastos por todas as pizzas! Utilize uma variável estática na classe `Pizza` para guardar esse tipo de informação (dica: utilize a classe `HashMap` para guardar o ingrediente como chave e um `Integer` como valor). Crie o método estático `contabilizaIngrediente()` para ser chamado dentro de `adicionaIngrediente()` e fazer esse registro.
>
> Crie uma nova classe chamada `CarrinhoDeCompras` que pode receber objetos da classe `Pizza`. Ela deve ter um método que retorna o valor total de todas as pizzas adicionadas. O carrinho não pode aceitar que seja adicionada uma pizza sem ingredientes.
>
> Crie uma classe `Principal` com o método `main()` que faz o seguinte:
>
> - Cria 3 pizzas com ingredientes diferentes.
> - Adiciona essas `Pizza`s em um `CarrinhoDeCompra`.
> - Imprime o total do `CarrinhoDeCompra`.
> - Imprime a quantidade utilizada de cada ingrediente.

Então, logo abaixo eu tentei fazer o cálculo do preço total mas ele me retorna o valor como zero. Fiquei algumas horas tentando achar qual poderia ser o erro que ele possui para me retornar somente zero, daí decidi vir aqui no stackoverflow onde já consegui solucionar muitas dúvidas minhas em C++.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza {

static HashMap<String, Integer> ingrediente = new HashMap<String, Integer>();   
ArrayList<String> qntdadeingre;
static int totalingre=0;
static int total=0;
static int preco=0;

public Pizza()
{
    this.qntdadeingre = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public static void contabilizaIngrediente(String ingredientes, Integer qntidade)
{
    ingrediente.put(ingredientes,qntidade);
}

public void adicionaIngrediente(String ingredientes)
{
    this.qntdadeingre.add(ingredientes);
    if(Pizza.ingrediente.containsKey(ingredientes)) {
        Pizza.contabilizaIngrediente(ingredientes, Pizza.ingrediente.get(ingredientes) + 1);
    } else {
        Pizza.contabilizaIngrediente(ingredientes, 1);
    }
}

public int getPreco()
{
    if(totalingre<=2)
    {
        preco=15;
    }else 
    {
        if(totalingre <= 5)
        {
            preco=20;
        }else
        {
            preco=23;
        }
    }
    total +=preco;

return total;
}

public int contemingr()
{
    if(qntdadeingre.size() > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getIngrediente()
{
     return ingrediente;
}

static void printatotal()
{
    System.out.println("Preco Final: " + totalingre);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos começar observando algumas coisas do seu código:

1. Não esqueça o modificador `private`. Dificilmente a visibilidade de pacote é o que você quer.
2. Não é boa prática abreviar ou comer letras dos nomes de variáveis, métodos, classes, etc. Assim sendo, `qntdadeingre`, `totalingre` e `contemingr` não são bons nomes. Também é boa ideia você respeitar a [convenção da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132), o que significa que quando os nomes de variáveis e métodos tiverem mais do que uma só palavra, você usará letras maiúsculas no nome das palavras subsequentes.
3. Se você já tem a lista de ingredientes (`qntdadeingre`), então você não precisa de uma variável para rastrear a quantidade de ingredientes (`totalingre`), basta verificar o tamanho da lista.
4. O método `contabilizaIngredientes` não deveria receber a quantidade de ingredientes a contabilizar, apenas o ingrediente a ser contabilizado. Esse método deve somar um à quantidade de tal ingrediente. A complexidade/responsabilidade de contabilizar esse ingrediente é algo que deveria estar apenas nesse método, mas se ele recebe a quantidade vinda de fora, então ele não estaria contabilizando, estaria apenas colocando no `HashMap`. Aliás, esse método deveria ser o único a utilizar o `HashMap`, vez que esse `HashMap` serve apenas aos propósitos internos desse método.
5. Há um princípio de programação orientada a objetos que diz para você depender de abstrações/interfaces e não de implementações. Ao utilizar variáveis dos tipos `ArrayList` e `HashMap` ao invés de `List` e `Map`, você está violando esse princípio.
6. Ao colocar o modificador `static` no campo `totalingre` você acabou fazendo com que todas as pizzas tivessem o mesmo preço! O preço tem que ser computado pela quantidade de ingredientes que há na pizza e não no total de pizzas.
7. Não use variáveis estáticas ou variáveis de instância para coisas que podem ser resolvidas com variáveis locais. Esse é o caso da sua variável `preco`.
8. Não há razão para contabilizar o preço total das pizzas, vez que o enunciado não pede nada disso. O que ele pede é o total das pizzas **dentro de um carrinho de compras**. Logo, a variável `total` está na classe errada e ela não vai computar o que você quer que seja nela computado.
9. Nomes no singular devem se referir para algo que representa uma única coisa, enquanto que nomes no plural deverão se referir a coleções de coisas. No entanto, você viola esse conceito ao fazer `ingrediente`, `qntdadeingre` serem coleções e `getIngrediente()` ser um método que retorna uma coleção enquanto que `ingredientes` é o nome de um só ingrediente.
10. Não use `int` para representar falso ou verdadeiro com 0 ou 1, use o tipo `boolean` com `true` ou `false`. Lembre-se que Java não é C ou C++!
11. Você ainda está longe do ponto onde poderá aprender o padrão MVC, mas saiba que misturar lógica de visualização com lógica de modelagem não é boa ideia. As classes `Pizza` e `CarrinhoDeCompras` servem para modelar conceitos do domínio do seu sistema. Já instruções do tipo `System.out.println` são parte da lógica de visualização, ou seja, para exibir informações ao usuário. Sei que esse é um conceito meio avançado para ser introduzido a você agora, mas tente não misturar coisas que servem para interagir com o usuário dentro de coisas que modelam o seu domínio. O seu método `printatotal()` é uma violação desse conceito pois ele interage com o usuário (exibindo uma mensagem), mas está dentro de uma classe de domínio (`Pizza`).

O seu código deveria ficar assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Pizza {
    private static final Map<String, Integer> quantidadesPorIngrediente = new HashMap<>();

    private final List<String> ingredientes;

    public Pizza() {
        ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static void contabilizaIngrediente(String ingrediente) {
        quantidadesPorIngrediente.compute(ingrediente, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
    }

    public void adicionaIngrediente(String ingrediente) {
        ingredientes.add(ingrediente);
        contabilizaIngrediente(ingrediente);
    }

    public boolean temIngredientes() {
        return !ingredientes.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getPreco() {
        int quantidadeIngredientes = ingredientes.size();
        return quantidadeIngredientes <= 2 ? 15 : quantidadeIngredientes <= 5 ? 20 : 23;
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getQuantidadesPorIngrediente() {
        return quantidadesPorIngrediente;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CarrinhoDeCompras {
    private final List<Pizza> pizzas;

    public CarrinhoDeCompras() {
        pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void adiciona(Pizza p) {
        if (!p.temIngredientes()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        pizzas.add(p);
    }

    public int getPreco() {
        int total = 0;
        for (Pizza p : pizzas) {
            total += p.getPreco();
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pizza marguerita = new Pizza();
        marguerita.adicionaIngrediente("Queijo");
        marguerita.adicionaIngrediente("Tomate");
        marguerita.adicionaIngrediente("Orégano");

        Pizza portuguesa = new Pizza();
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Queijo");
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Presunto");
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Ovo");
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Calabresa");
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Cebola");
        portuguesa.adicionaIngrediente("Tomate");

        Pizza brigadeiro = new Pizza();
        brigadeiro.adicionaIngrediente("Brigadeiro derretido");

        CarrinhoDeCompras c1 = new CarrinhoDeCompras();
        c1.adiciona(marguerita);
        c1.adiciona(portuguesa);
        c1.adiciona(brigadeiro);
        System.out.println("Preço do carrinho: " + c1.getPreco());

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : Pizza.getQuantidadesPorIngrediente().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("O ingrediente " + entry.getKey() + " foi usado " + entry.getValue() + " vezes.");
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída que é produzida:

```
Preço do carrinho: 58
O ingrediente Queijo foi usado 2 vezes.
O ingrediente Cebola foi usado 1 vezes.
O ingrediente Tomate foi usado 2 vezes.
O ingrediente Ovo foi usado 1 vezes.
O ingrediente Orégano foi usado 1 vezes.
O ingrediente Calabresa foi usado 1 vezes.
O ingrediente Presunto foi usado 1 vezes.
O ingrediente Brigadeiro derretido foi usado 1 vezes.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/raGWSp)

Agora, vou dar algumas observações sobre alguns problemas do enunciado do exercício:

- Usar um `HashMap` estático não é uma boa prática de programação orientada a objetos. Esse `HashMap` nada mais é do que uma variável global, que é uma má prática de programação mesmo na programação estruturada do C. Exercícios que ensinam, sugerem ou estimulem más práticas de programação não são bons (a menos que eles esclareçam tal fato posteriormente). O ideal seria que essa contabilização de ingredientes tivesse algum contexto representado por algum objeto, tal como uma `Pizzaria`. Em programas orientados-a-objetos bem escritos, você vai encontrar poucos campos/atributos com o modificador `static` que não sejam constantes numéricas ou strings.
- Se a ideia é aprender programação orientada a objetos, o ingrediente deveria ser representado por uma classe `Ingrediente`, e não por uma simples `String`.
- O exercício não diz o que acontece se tentar-se criar uma pizza com ingredientes repetidos. A implementação acima deixa isso acontecer e contabiliza múltiplas vezes o ingrediente repetido.
- O exercício diz que pizzas sem ingredientes devem ser recusadas, mas não diz exatamente qual mecanismo de recusa deve ser utilizado. No caso, utilizei uma exceção para sinalizar a recusa. E embora ele peça para codificar essa recusa, ele não pede para exercitá-la no `main`.
- Construir pizzas sem ingredientes para depois ir acrescentando-os não é uma das melhores práticas de programação, vez que ela leva o programador ao vício de criar objetos que são construídos incompletos para serem então preenchidos posteriormente (e esse vício é extremamente comum e difundido e difícil de ser combatido). O ideal é que o construtor já devolva o objeto pronto para ser utilizado com todos os seus campos definidos de forma adequada. [**Veja mais nessa outra pergunta.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/132) Nesse caso, o ideal seria que o construtor de `Pizza` já recebesse todos os ingredientes a serem utilizados como parâmetros do construtor.

Comment: É este tipo de resposta que eu gosto, ainda que eu discorde pontualmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado por ter esclarecido minhas duvidas. Pois como eu disse estou tentando aprender uma outra linguagem fora as q já aprendi ao longo do curso. Conheci este curso de orientado a objeto através de um amigo por isso eu não saberia dizer se estou aprendendo corretamente ou não.

Comment: Para guardar ingredientes sem levar em conta as quantidades o exercício poderia ter sugerido um `Set`/`HashSet`. Se for levá-las em conta existe uma coleção do Guava que cai bem aí, se não me engano se chama `MultiSet`, embora naturalmente sair das coleções fornecidas pelo Java seja "avançado". E um ponto sobre expor a variável `quantidadesPorIngrediente` através do método `getQuantidadesPorIngrediente()`: ela fica sujeita a modificação indevida do lado de fora da classe. Talvez fosse o caso de expor uma cópia da mesma no lugar.

Comment: @Piovezan Sim, eu nem entrei nos detalhes sobre expor o `Map`. Isso viola o encapsulamento da classe, mas necessitaria de umas abordagens mais avançadas para resolver. Um `return Collections.unmodifiableMap(quantidadesPorIngrediente);` resolveria parte disso, mas o melhor mesmo seria fazer esse método ter um `BiConsumer<String, Integer>` como parâmetro.