# Como usar o super em java?

Tags: java, herança, superclasse

Eu sei o básico do super, mas por exemplo : Se eu tiver uma classe mae Pessoa com atributos nome,idade e sexo, e uma classe filha Aluno com atributos curso,matricula e periodo, e uma classe filha de Aluno que se chama Bolsista, como eu tenho que colocar no super todos os atributos de Aluno e Pessoa, tipo super(nome,idade,sexo,curso,matricula,periodo)? Porque eu fiz isso em um codigo mas da erro. Não da pra postar porque se eu colocar todas as classes aqui vai ficar bem grande e dificil de entender D:

Comment: Adicionei algumas perguntas relacionadas além da duplicata que podem te ajudar a entender melhor o `super`

Comment: Referência conceitual independente de linguagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/64969

Comment: Você não colocaria tudo no super. Colocaria cada atributo na classe em que ele foi declarado. Assim você teria o construtor de Bolsista passando todos os valores dos atributos `Bolsista(nome,idade,sexo,curso,matricula,periodo)`, como não há nenhum atributo para setar, só chama o super (Aluno) para setar o resto `super(nome,idade,sexo,curso,matricula, periodo)`. Daí setava o curso, a matricula e o período, e chamava o super (Pessoa) para setar o resto `super(nome, idade)`.