# Leitura de ficheiros em Java

Tags: java, array

```
public static void loadfile(stock []a) throws IOException{

        String fich;
        File fichDad;
        int i=countDatas(a);

        while(sc.nextLine().length()!=0);
        do{
            System.out.print("\nQual é o nome do ficheiro que deseja ler?\n");
            fich=sc.nextLine();
            fichDad = new File(fich);
        }while(!fichDad.canRead()||!fichDad.exists()||!fichDad.isFile());

        Scanner lerFil = new Scanner (fichDad);

        while (lerFil.hasNextLine()){
            if(i==100) break;
            if(!lerFil.hasNext()) break;; 

            a[i]=new stock();
            a[i].nome=lerFil.next();
            a[i].quant=lerFil.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        System.out.print("\n\n\nValores inseridos com sucesso!\n\n\n\n");

        lerFil.close();

}
```

Eu estou a fazer um exercício que consiste num programa (em Java) para manutenção de stock numa loja. O programa está a funcionar, mas tem um "problema" que não consigo resolver. O programa faz todas as operações corretamente e depois o progresso feito pode ser guardado num ficheiro, ficheiro esse que pode depois ser lido e carregado para o programa para retomar o progresso. No entanto, se ler o ficheiros duas vezes seguidas, em vez de apagar o que tem na memória e escrever por cima, a função apresenta duas vezes o conteúdo do ficheiro. Alguém tem uma solução?

Comment: pode compartilhar o seu código que faz a leitura?

Comment: peço desculpa, tinha me esquecido de adicionar. ja adicionei

Comment: O que é `countDatas(a)`?

Comment: De onde vem a variável `sc`? Porque você limpa toda a entrada dela?

Comment: countDatas(a) é uma funçao que conta o numero de elementos no array. sc é o scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode reescrever sua classe `Stock` assim:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Stock {
    private final String nome;
    private final int quantidade;

    public Stock(String nome, int quantidade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public static List<Stock> loadFile(Scanner sc) throws IOException {
        // Limpa o sc.
        while (!sc.nextLine().isEmpty());

        File ficheiro;
        do {
            System.out.print("\nQual é o nome do ficheiro que deseja ler?\n");
            String nomeFicheiro = sc.nextLine();
            ficheiro = new File(nomeFicheiro);
        } while (!ficheiro.exists() || !ficheiro.isFile() || !ficheiro.canRead());

        List<Stock> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner leitor = new Scanner(ficheiro)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 && leitor.hasNext(); i++) {
                String nome = leitor.next();
                int quantidade = leitor.nextInt();
                Stock s = new Stock(nome, quantidade);
                lista.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Valores inseridos com sucesso!");

        return lista;
    }
}
```

Observe que ele sempre devolverá uma nova lista de `Stock` contendo o conteúdo do arquivo. Use o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) e siga [convenções de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132).

Para substituir então a lista, basta fazer isso:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// Primeira vez.
List<Stock> lista = Stock.loadFile(sc);

// ...Um monte de código aqui...

// Segunda vez.
lista = Stock.loadFile(sc);
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: mas nao existe maneira de fazer sem usar construtores e listas?

Comment: @MartimNeves Certamente que existe. Você pode usar arrays no lugar de listas (inclusive você usava) ou bolar a sua própria estrutura de dados equivalente para guardar a sequência de dados e pode construir objetos chamando os setters posteriormente ou diretamente nos atributos (tal como você fazia). Entretanto, não recomendo nenhuma dessas abordagens, motivo pelo qual fiz a resposta exatamente dessa forma. Trabalhar com arrays é algo um tanto difícil e listas são muito mais flexíveis e fáceis de se lidar. Quanto a usar os construtores, deve-se a isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132

Comment: muito obrigado!