# Como validar os dados passados para um construtor?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor

Existe uma maneira de tratar possíveis erros ou validações ao instanciar uma classe usando o construtor?  Por exemplo, esse é meu construtor:

```
public boolean ContaFisica(int agenciaConta, int numeroConta, int digitoConta, String tipoConta, String senha, String confirmacaoSenha) {
    if(! senha.equals(confirmacaoSenha)) {
        return false;
    }
    this.agenciaConta = agenciaConta;
    this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    this.digitoConta = digitoConta;
    this.tipoConta = tipoConta;
    return true;
}
```

Perceba que ele dá um `return false` quando as senhas não coincidem. 
Já no meu código para instanciar a classe poderia ficar assim:

```
if(ContaFisica conta1 = new ContaFisica(2442, 8053, 5, "CP", "1234", "1234")) {
    //DEU CERTO
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você não criou um construtor. Na verdade você criou um método que retorna um `boolean`, e que por acaso tem o mesmo nome da classe. Mas quando você faz `new ContaFisica(...)`, está chamando o construtor, não o método.

Construtores não devem ter o tipo de retorno declarado, pois eles já retornam uma instância da própria classe. Se quer validar algo no construtor e só criar a instância se todos os dados forem válidos, você pode lançar uma exceção caso algum dado seja inválido:

```
public ContaFisica(int agenciaConta, int numeroConta, int digitoConta, String tipoConta, String senha, String confirmacaoSenha) {
    if (!senha.equals(confirmacaoSenha)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Senha deve ser igual a confirmação da senha");
    }
    this.agenciaConta = agenciaConta;
    this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    this.digitoConta = digitoConta;
    this.tipoConta = tipoConta;
}
```

Para saber se caiu no caso inválido, basta capturar a exceção com um `try`/`catch`:

```
try {
    ContaFisica conta = new ContaFisica(123, 456, 7, "tipo", "senha", "senhadiferente");
    // conta criada, fazer o que quiser com ela
    ....
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Não foi possível criar a conta: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

---

As outras respostas sugerem criar a conta e depois chamar um método para validar se a conta está com todos os dados válidos, ou criar um outro campo indicando se ela é válida ou não.

Você tem que avaliar se faz sentido criar uma conta com dados inválidos - se não fizer (e eu acredito que não faz, mas só tendo todo o contexto e requisitos do seu sistema para saber), nem crie a conta, lance a exceção antes.

Leia também:

- [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052)
- [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101)

---

<sup>*Sobre criar um método com o mesmo nome da classe: embora seja possível, [não é uma boa ideia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18481060).*</sup>

Comment: Vai nesse cara, boa explicação!

Comment: Tem essa aqui também que fala sobre validação antes do construtor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101 Aí tem muitas informações importantes e os padrões que se costumam usar.

Comment: @Maniero Adicionei o link na resposta, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Construtor não pode retornar nada além da classe em questão.

Exemplo: `new ContaFisica(bla, bla, bla);` retorna apenas o Object `ContaFisica`, sendo assim como poderia retornar um `boolean`?

É por este fato que NÃO é necessário colocar `void` ou o tipo de retorno no construtor, pois está explicito que é o Object da Classe.
O ideal é você criar um método para fazer essa verificação que necessária.

Ex:

```
ContaFisica conta1 = new ContaFisica(2442, 8053, 5, "CP", "1234", "1234");
if(conta1.validar()) 
{
    //
}
```

Comment: entendi! então eu criaria um método para verificar se no construtor, todo o código foi rodado com sucesso?!!

Comment: Poderia sim!!!.

Comment: To triste com meu comentário agora, só tentei ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Voce poderia lançar uma exceção ou ainda criar um novo atributo `this.valido = true | false`, além do mais Construtor não pode retornar nada além de um novo objeto da classe.
Por exemplo:

```
public boolean ContaFisica(int agenciaConta, int numeroConta, int digitoConta, String tipoConta, String senha, String confirmacaoSenha) {
    if(! senha.equals(confirmacaoSenha)) {
        throw new Exeption('Senhas não coincidem');
    }
    this.agenciaConta = agenciaConta;
    this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    this.digitoConta = digitoConta;
    this.tipoConta = tipoConta;
    return true;
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
public boolean ContaFisica(int agenciaConta, int numeroConta, int digitoConta, String tipoConta, String senha, String confirmacaoSenha) {
    if(! senha.equals(confirmacaoSenha)) {
        this.valida = false;
    }
    this.agenciaConta = agenciaConta;
    this.numeroConta = numeroConta;
    this.digitoConta = digitoConta;
    this.tipoConta = tipoConta;
    this.valida = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Os construtores de classes por definição tem como retorno uma nova instancia da classe. A partir do momento que você define um outro tipo como retorno, esta passa a ser um método de classe, e não mais um construtor. No seu caso, nada impede que você crie um construtor comum, recebendo os valores e setando os atributos da classe, e crie um método acessório que lhe diga se a senha e a confirmação são iguais.

Como por exemplo a classe abaixo:

```
class ClasseA {
    private Long atributoA;
    private Long atributoB;

    public ClasseA(Long atributoA, Long atributoB) {
        this.atributoA = atributoA;
        this.atributoB = atributoB;
    }

    public boolean atributoAIgualAtributoB() {
        return this.atributoA.equals(this.atributoB) ;
    }
}
```

Instanciando assim:

```
    final ClasseA classeA = new ClasseA(1L, 2L);

    if(classeA.atributoAIgualAtributoB()) {
        //DEU CERTO
    }
```

Onde você pode verifica essa igualdade e tratá-la com uma exceção.