# Cálculo de idade em Java

Tags: java, data

Eu tenho um código que deveria calcular a idade, porém no meu teste eu não consigo pegar o dia e nem o mês da `Data` e ainda a idade vem errado devido isso. No teste retorna 32 anos, enquanto deveria ser 31.

```
public Data(Integer day, Integer month, Integer year) {
    if(month < 1 && month > 12) {
        System.out.println("Informe um mes valido.");
    }
    if (day < 1 && day > 31) {
        System.out.println("Tem que ser de 1 a 31!!!");
    }
    if (year > 2020) {
        System.out.println("Ano invalido");
    }
    if (validarData(day, month, year)) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
}

public boolean validarData (Integer dayV, Integer monthV, Integer yearV) {
    boolean dayOk = false;
    if (monthV == 4 || monthV == 6 || monthV == 9 || monthV == 11) {
        if (dayV <= 30) {
            dayOk = true;
        } else {
            dayOk = false;
        }
    }

    if (monthV == 1 || monthV == 3 || monthV == 5 || monthV == 7 || monthV == 8 || monthV == 10 || monthV == 12) {
        if (dayV <= 31) {
            dayOk = true;
        } else {
            dayOk = false;
        }
    }
    if (monthV == 2) {
        if (yearV % 4 == 0) {
            if (dayV <= 29) {
                dayOk = true;
            } else {
                dayOk = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (dayV <= 28) {
                dayOk = true;
            } else {
                dayOk = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dayOk) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static int calculoIdade(Data data) {
    Calendar cHoje= Calendar.getInstance();
    return cHoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) - data.year;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Data data = new Data(03, 11, 1988);
    System.out.println("Idade: " + calculoIdade(data));

}
```

Comment: Nada pode ser simultaneamente menor que 1 **e** maior que 31. Talvez você deseje fazer ` if (day < 1 || day > 31) {`, idem `{if(month < 1 || month > 12) {`, ou no lugar de e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No cálculo, você só está levando em conta o ano, mas também deve verificar se o aniversário da pessoa já passou (se não passou, tem que subtrair 1 da idade). Assim:

```
public static int calculoIdade(Data dataNascimento) {
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    int idade = hoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dataNascimento.year;
    // se ainda não chegou o aniversário, diminui 1 ano
    int mesAtual = hoje.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    if ((mesAtual == dataNascimento.month && hoje.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dataNascimento.day)
        || mesAtual < dataNascimento.month) {
        idade--;
    }
    return idade;
}
```

Um detalhe chato é que na classe [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) os meses [são indexados em zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), por isso tem que somar 1 para obter o valor correto do mês (já que sua classe `Data` parece usar os valores corretos: janeiro 1, fevereiro 2, etc).

Depois eu vejo se a pessoa ainda não fez aniversário neste ano. Ou seja:

- se está no mesmo mês e ainda não chegou o dia do aniversário, ou
- se ainda não chegou o mês do aniversário

Se alguma das condições acima ocorrer, é porque o aniversário deste ano ainda não ocorreu, e nesse caso deve-se diminuir 1 da idade.

---

Há outros detalhes a se atentar.

No construtor, caso algum valor seja inválido, você imprime a respectiva mensagem de erro, mas prossegue criando a data mesmo assim. Mas se o valor for inválido, a `Data` nem deveria ser criada. Em vez disso, ela deveria lançar uma exceção (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406760/112052)).

Além disso, dá para simplificar a lógica de verificar o dia baseado no mês. Vale lembrar também que um [ano bissexto é aquele que é divisível por 4, **exceto** se for divisível por 100 (a menos que seja também divisível por 400)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Enfim, uma sugestão para o construtor e a validação da data seria:

```
public Data(int day, int month, int year) {
    validarData(day, month, year);
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
}

private void validarData(int day, int month, int year) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Informe um mês válido.");
    }
    if (year > 2020) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ano inválido");
    }
    // primeiro calcula a quantidade de dias do mês
    int qtdDias;
    if (month == 2) {
        // ano bissexto, divisível por 4 (mas se for divisível por 100, só é bissexto se for divisível por 400)
        if (year % 4 == 0 && ((year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0)) {
            qtdDias = 29;
        } else {
            qtdDias = 28;
        }
    } else if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
        qtdDias = 31;
    } else {
        qtdDias = 30;
    }
    // verifica se o dia está no intervalo válido
    if (day < 1 || day > qtdDias) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dia tem que ser de 1 a " + qtdDias);
    }
}
```

Deixei o método `validarData` como `private`, pois parece que só é usado pela própria classe para validar. Se algum valor for inválido, ele lança a exceção e a instância não é criada (já que não faz sentido validar, informar que o valor é errado e criar a instância mesmo assim).

Repare que a condição do dia e do mês usa o operador `||` ("ou") e não `&&` ("e"). Isso porque não tem como o mês ser ao mesmo tempo menor que 1 e maior que 12 (ou é um, ou outro, ou nenhum, só não tem como ser ambos ao mesmo tempo), então se usasse `&&`, nunca entraria no `if`.

Também mudei os campos de `Integer` para `int`, pois não me parece haver motivo para usar os *wrappers* - leia mais a respeito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157994/112052).

---

### Use uma API de datas

Se for apenas um exercício, tudo bem tentar implementar uma classe que represente uma data. Mas se for para código em produção, use o que já tem pronto.

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Para calcular a idade, ficaria assim:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public static int calculoIdade(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    return (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia), LocalDate.now());
}
```

A diferença é que o [método `between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) retorna um `long`, mas se você sabe que o valor sempre será menor que 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (pouco mais de 2 bilhões), pode fazer o *cast* para `int` sem problemas.

E a própria classe [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) já verifica os valores do dia, mês e ano, se é bissexto, etc, e lança uma [exceção](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DateTimeException.html) se algum deles for inválido. Você só precisaria adicionar a condição de verificar se ano é maior que 2020, que é específica do seu código.

Para versões anteriores ao JDK 8, dá para usar o próprio `Calendar`. Ou, para JDK 6 e 7 existe o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. A maioria das funcionalidades do Java 8 está presente, mas em vez das classes estarem no pacote `java.time`, elas ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (tirando isso, o código acima ficaria igual).

---

## 29 de fevereiro

Vale lembrar que há um *corner case*. Se a pessoa nasceu, por exemplo, em 29 de fevereiro de 2020, quantos anos ela terá em 28 de fevereiro de 2021?

Os códigos acima consideram que a idade será zero, pois ainda não chegou o aniversário dela. Mas como no ano 2021, fevereiro só tem 28 dias, então somente a partir de 1 de março é que será considerado que a idade é 1.

Se quiser considerar que em ano não bissextos, o dia 28 de fevereiro é o "aniversário", terá que colocar esta regra nos seus métodos.

Na sua classe `Data`, ficaria:

```
private static boolean bissexto(int ano) {
    return ano % 4 == 0 && ((ano % 100) != 0 || (ano % 400) == 0);
}

public static int calculoIdade(Data dataNascimento) {
    Calendar hoje = Calendar.getInstance();
    int idade = hoje.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dataNascimento.year;
    // se ainda não chegou o aniversário, diminui 1 ano
    int mesAtual = hoje.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int diaAtual = hoje.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if ((mesAtual == dataNascimento.month && diaAtual < dataNascimento.day) || mesAtual < dataNascimento.month) {
        // mas se nasceu em 29/02 e hoje é 28/02 (e o ano não é bissexto), não subtrai
        if (!(diaAtual == 28 && mesAtual == 2
              && dataNascimento.day == 29 && dataNascimento.month == 2
              && !bissexto(hoje.get(Calendar.YEAR))))
            idade--;
    }
    return idade;
}
```

Repare que criei um método auxiliar para verificar se o ano é bissexto.
Mas com o `java.time` você pode usar a classe [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html), que possui um método pronto para verificar isso:

```
public static int calculoIdade(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
    int idade = (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia), hoje);
    // se nasceu em 29/02 e hoje é 28/02 (e o ano não é bissexto), soma 1 na idade
    if (dia == 29 && mes == 2 && hoje.getDayOfMonth() == 28
        && hoje.getMonthValue() == 2 && !Year.isLeap(hoje.getYear()))
        idade++;
    return idade;
}
```

Para uma discussão mais completa sobre verificação de anos bissextos, veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495688/112052).

Comment: Voce me deu uma aula de java, que não me lembro de ter uma explicação tão detalhada. Essa da classe Calendar que indexa janeiro como Zero, não sabia mesmo não; Mas se ainda puder me explicar so a questão dos Ifs que voce me disse que ele nao vailda 2 coisas ao mesmo tempo, if month < 1 && month > 12. no Python eu uso muito se isso é igual aquilo e mais aquilo outro entao faz tal coisa.

Comment: @TiagoTFDias São 2 condições diferentes. Se vc testa `if (day >= 1 && day <= 31)`, verifica se o dia é ao mesmo tempo maior ou igual a 1 e menor ou igual a 31, e aí funciona tanto em Java qto em Python. Mas vc estava fazendo `if (day < 1 && day > 31)` (se o dia é menor que 1 e maior que 31), e aí nunca será verdadeiro, pois nenhum número é ao mesmo tempo menor que 1 e maior que 31.

Comment: @TiagoTFDias Outra coisa: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Comment: A tah, agora eu entendi a logica dos ifs que eu tava fazendo. vdd. Agradeço muito, vou votar sim, e se isso ajudar outras pessoas me deixa bem também.