# Como verificar se um ano é bissexto em Java?

Tags: java, data

Como saber se o ano atual - na verdade, se qualquer ano - é bissexto?

Sendo que eu posso ter apenas o valor numérico do ano, ou então um objeto que representa uma data (seja [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), etc), a forma de verificar seria a mesma para todos os casos?

Comment: Antes que alguém estranhe que eu mesmo respondi minha própria pergunta, isso é [**perfeitamente aceitável e dentro das regras**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Inclusive, a [página de fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) tem uma [opção para postar a própria resposta juntamente com a pergunta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPEQw.png). Claro que se alguém tiver uma resposta melhor e mais completa, com certeza deve postá-la. O objetivo é trazer este conhecimento para o site (pois fiz uma busca e não tinha encontrado nada a respeito).

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Cálculo de idade em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462189/c%c3%a1lculo-de-idade-em-java)

Comment: @RicardoPontual Creio que não é dup: na outra pergunta o foco principal é o cálculo da idade (que claro, tem que considerar os anos bissextos), mas a verificação do ano bissexto em si é um detalhe ali (e além disso, por parecer um exercício, só foi sugerido o cálculo "manual"). Aqui o foco é somente a verificação do ano bissexto (e nem toco no assunto de cálculo de idade ou qualquer outro caso de aritmética de datas)

Comment: @hkotsubo resumiria (editando a outra pergunta) e na outra colocaria um link dessa resposta, baseado na proposta aqui, que é *"se já usa uma API de data ou não"*, ficando a critério do leitor. ps: parabéns pela iniciativa.

Comment: Eu até responderia mas o cara que respondeu manja muito mais do que eu e tive que dar um +1 para ele. Brincadeiras a parte, eu fico desconfortável quando temos que dar explicações de nossos atos já prevendo retaliações devido ao desconhecimento da comunidade sobre o funcionamento do site, não falo dos usuários mais velhos ou novatos já engajados mas sim daqueles usuários que uma orientações sobre o uso da plataforma é uma ofensa mortal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer, e varia conforme os dados que você já tem e/ou a versão do Java.

---

## Tenho somente o valor numérico do ano

Se você já tem o valor numérico do ano (em um `int` ou `long`, por exemplo), e **está usando Java >= 8**, pode usar a [classe `java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html), que possui o [método estático `isLeap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#isLeap(long)) (esse é o mais "rápido" e direto, e não precisa criar nenhum objeto, pois é apenas uma chamada de método estático):

```
int ano = 2000;
System.out.println(Year.isLeap(ano)); // true
```

Para **Java <= 7**, use [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) (infelizmente não é tão direto, pois tem que criar uma instância e depois obter a quantidade de dias do ano):

```
int ano = 2000;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ano);
// se a quantidade de dias do ano for maior que 365, é bissexto
System.out.println(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365); // true
```

Outra opção é usar [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) (também precisa criar uma instância), que possui o [método `isLeapYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear(int)):

```
int ano = 2000;
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println(cal.isLeapYear(ano)); // true
```

---

Lembrando que as classes acima usam a regra do [Calendário Gregoriano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar): se o ano é divisível por 100, só é bissexto se for divisível por 400, e se não for divisível por 100, só é bissexto se for divisível por 4). Claro que se quiser, você pode implementar essa regra manualmente:

```
public static boolean bissexto(int ano) {
    return (ano % 4 == 0) && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0);
}
```

Mas se já existe pronto na API nativa, não vejo motivo para reinventar a roda...

**Só tem um detalhe**: `GregorianCalendar` possui uma "data de corte", que no caso é o ano 1582, quando foi oficializado o Calendário Gregoriano - mais precisamente, `1582-10-15T00:00:00Z`: 15 de outubro de 1582, à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (nota: [nem todos os países adotaram a mudança de calendário em 1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar), mas é esta data que está configurada na classe quando uma instância é criada).

Isso quer dizer que para datas anteriores a essa, ele considera a regra do [Calendário Juliano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), na qual basta ser divisível por 4 para que seja bissexto: ou seja, usando `GregorianCalendar`, 1900 não é bissexto, pois é maior que 1582 e cai na regra de ser múltiplo de 100 mas não de 400; mas 1500 é considerado bissexto por ser menor que 1582, então a regra do múltiplo de 400 não se aplica.

Mas é possível mudar este comportamento setando uma data de corte diferente:

```
int ano = 1500;
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
// 1500 é anterior à data de corte (1582) e usa a regra antiga (basta ser divísivel por 4)
System.out.println(cal.isLeapYear(ano)); // true

cal.setGregorianChange(new Date(-62135758799190L)); // mudar data de corte para 1 de janeiro do ano 1

// agora 1500 não é mais considerado bissexto (usa a regra atual: múltiplos de 100 só são bissextos se forem divisíveis por 400)
System.out.println(cal.isLeapYear(ano)); // false
```

Lembrando que somente `GregorianCalendar` faz isso. Já `Calendar.getInstance()` **pode ou não** fazer, pois o método `getInstance` pode retornar um `GregorianCalendar`, mas também pode retornar outras implementações, de acordo com o *locale default* que está configurado na JVM. Por exemplo, para o *locale* `th_TH` (tailandês), `getInstance` retorna um `BuddhistCalendar` (que implementa o Calendário Budista), e que no caso considera que 1500 não é bissexto:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("th", "TH"));
int ano = 2000;

// no locale th_TH, não é criado um GregorianCalendar
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal2.getClass()); // class sun.util.BuddhistCalendar
cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR, ano);
System.out.println(cal2.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365); // false

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
System.out.println(cal.isLeapYear(ano)); // true
```

No caso, você pode forçar a criação de um `GregorianCalendar` setando o *locale* (`Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"))`, por exemplo - a grande maioria dos *locales* retorna um `GregorianCalendar`).

Já `Year.isLeap` considera que 1500 não é bissexto, não havendo uma forma de configurar uma data de corte (sempre é usada a regra do múltiplo de 400).

Mas isso é para um valor numérico qualquer. Se quer o ano **atual**, use `Year.now().isLeap()` (nesse caso não tem jeito, precisa criar uma instância de `Year` correspondente ao ano atual). E para `Calendar`, basta não setar o ano (não chame `set(Calendar.YEAR, ano)`), pois `getInstance()` já retorna a data atual.

---

## E se eu já tiver um objeto que representa uma data?

#### Java <= 7

No caso de ter um `Calendar`, basta usar os métodos acima.

Se tiver um `Date`, **não** recomendo usar o [método `getYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#getYear()), por 2 motivos:

- este método retorna o valor do ano normalizado em 1900. Ou seja, ele subtrai 1900 do ano (por exemplo, para a data atual - ano 2021 - `new Date().getYear()` retorna `121`), então você tem que lembrar de somar 1900 (caso queira usar algum dos métodos acima)
- este método está *deprecated* desde o Java 1.1 e a própria documentação recomenda o uso de `Calendar`, sendo assim, o correto seria:

  ```
  Date date = // um Date qualquer
  // cria um Calendar usando o Date
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  // usar os métodos já indicados acima
  ```

Lembrando que, se quiser a data atual, não precisa criar um `Date`, basta usar `Calendar.getInstance()`.

#### Java >= 8 (`java.time`)

Para `LocalDate`, basta usar o [método `isLeapYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isLeapYear()):

```
LocalDate date = // um LocalDate qualquer;
System.out.println(date.isLeapYear());
```

E para os demais tipos do `java.time`, você pode obter o valor do ano e passar para `Year.isLeap`, ou obter o `LocalDate` nos casos em que isso é aplicável (ou ainda, obter o `Year` a partir do objeto):

```
LocalDateTime dt = // um LocalDateTime qualquer

// passar o valor do ano para Year.isLeap
System.out.println(Year.isLeap(dt.getYear()));

// ou obter o LocalDate
System.out.println(dt.toLocalDate().isLeapYear());

// ou obter o Year a partir do objeto
System.out.println(Year.from(dt).isLeap());
```

A primeira forma (usar `getYear`) é mais direta e - na minha opinião - mais simples. A vantagem é que os tipos de data nativos da API (os que possuem o ano, claro) já têm este *getter* (exceto, claro, `LocalTime` e `OffsetTime`, que só tem os campos de horário, `MonthDay`, que só possui dia e mês, além de `Instant`, `Month` e `DayOfWeek`, que também não possuem o ano).

A segunda forma pode parecer mais desvantajosa por criar uma instância `LocalDate`, mas na implementação atual, os tipos usam [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/112052) e encapsulam uma instância de `LocalDate`, que é retornada por `toLocalDate` (ou seja, não há a criação de uma nova instância). De qualquer forma, como é um detalhe de implementação, não convém confiar cegamente nesta característica, caso não seja desejável a criação de novas instâncias desnecessariamente.

A terceira forma (`Year.from`) é mais indicada quando você está trabalhando com um `TemporalAccessor` (uma interface que todos os tipos de data implementam), sem se importar muito com o tipo específico do objeto em questão: tudo que interessa é que ele tenha o campo referente ao ano. Assim, seria possível ter, por exemplo, um método que recebe qualquer uma das classes de data da API (e qualquer outra que implemente `TemporalAccessor`) e consiga verificar se o ano é bissexto:

```
static boolean bissexto(TemporalAccessor t) {
    return Year.from(t).isLeap();
}

...
// funciona com qualquer tipo que implemente TemporalAccessor e tenha o campo referente ao ano
System.out.println(bissexto(LocalDate.now()));
System.out.println(bissexto(LocalDateTime.now()));

String string = // uma string qualquer contendo a data
DateTimeFormatter fmt = // um DateTimeFormatter que faz parsing da string acima
// não preciso transformar o resultado do parse em uma instância específica de nenhuma das classes da API
// posso passar o TemporalAccessor diretamente para o método "bissexto"
System.out.println(bissexto(fmt.parse(string)));
```

Se bem que para o último caso, eu preferiria usar um `TemporalQuery`, que pode ser passado diretamente para o método `parse`:

```java
TemporalQuery<Boolean> isLeapYear = (t) -> Year.from(t).isLeap();

String string = "10/01/2020";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
System.out.println(fmt.parse(string, isLeapYear)); // true
```

---

### Outros calendários

As regras acima valem para o calendário ISO 8601 (de forma resumida, é como se aplicássemos a regra do Calendário Gregoriano de forma retroativa, para datas anteriores a outubro de 1582 - que é a "data de corte" mencionada acima). Basicamente, este é o calendário *default* do `java.time`, usado implícita e internamente pelas [classes principais da API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html).

Mas o `java.time` também dá suporte para outros calendários - as implementações disponíveis se encontram no [pacote `java.time.chrono`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/package-summary.html). Por exemplo, a classe `ThaiBuddhistChronology` (que implementa o [Calendário Budista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar)) possui uma regra diferente para anos bissextos. Veja abaixo um exemplo comparando com `IsoChronology` (que implementa as regras já mencionadas acima):

```
int ano = 2020;
System.out.println(IsoChronology.INSTANCE.isLeapYear(ano)); // true
System.out.println(ThaiBuddhistChronology.INSTANCE.isLeapYear(ano)); // false

ano = 2543;
System.out.println(IsoChronology.INSTANCE.isLeapYear(ano)); // false
System.out.println(ThaiBuddhistChronology.INSTANCE.isLeapYear(ano)); // true
```

Enfim, para outros calendários, basta usar a respectiva classe do pacote `java.time.chrono`. Ou, se precisar de outros calendários (e não quiser implementá-los), o jeito é recorrer a bibliotecas externas. Dois exemplos são o projeto [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/package-summary.html) (do mesmo criador do `java.time`) e o [Time4j](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/): ambos possuem suporte para vários outros calendários.