# O método construtor pode ter validação?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação, construtor

Eu quero saber, se posso adicionar validação no método construtor do meu modelo de domínio. Isso é uma má prática?

O que eu tenho atualmente, é algo como:

```
final class Example
{
   public function __construct(private readonly int $value)
   {
       if ($this->value <= 0) {
           throw new LogicException('The value cannot be negative.');
       }
   }
}
```

Mas isso seria uma abordagem ruim? Seria melhor encapsular em um método privado, com um nome explícito para essa validação, e apenas fazer sua chamada no método construtor?

```
final class Example
{
    public function __construct(private readonly int $value)
    {
        $this->validateIfValueIsNegative();
    }

    private function validateIfValueIsNegative(): void
    {
        if ($this->value <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('The value cannot be negative.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu bem opinião, mas, eu vejo que a parte de validação seria outra classe e no método construtor você faria as devidas validações

Comment: Mas se o modelo não contiver as validações não ficaria anêmico? Básicamente, ele quem deveria saber como se validar, e se comportar.

Comment: você deve validar todas as vezes, só dei a dica que você tenha uma classe de validação para não repetir código no decorrer do seu sistema, lembrando que um sistema terá mais classes para validar e validações repetidas, esse foi o meu foco, não faria a validação na própria classe!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das [funções mais importantes do construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) é inicializar o objeto em estado válido. Isso quer dizer que se você receber dados inválidos para construir o objeto ele não deve ser construído. Ou seja, deve fazer a validação, na maioria das situações.

Se quer validar antes tem como fazer também, isso foi discutido em [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101).

A questão parece focar mais no caso de fazer sim a validação mas dentro do próprio construtor ou não. Por outro lado no comentário parece querer saber se deve ter validação ou não.

Do ponto de vista da melhor legibilidade possível o ideal é que faça separado e adote o [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101), então do ponto de vista mais conceitual a segunda forma é mais adequada.

Mais ainda, se a validação será usada em alguma outra parte da classe então passa ser quase obrigatória que seja assim, até para não violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Pandas morrerão se você não usa em outro lugar e resolve apenas fazer a validação dentro do construtor? Não, nada de ruim acontecerá, seu código não ficará pior na prática, e de sob certo ponto de vista pode ser até melhor por já ver a validação ali onde ela é usada. As coisas não são sempre boas ou ruins, tem muita situação que é subjetiva, contextual e até irrelevante, na prática.

Eu estou mais preocupado se está criando classes sem necessidade, se está usando classe em algo simples, ou se está usando uma linguagem que originalmente foi criada para fazer *scripts* e agora incentiva fazer código *enterprise*, ou se usa exceção para lógica de negócios, o que não tem muito com fazer em um construtor a não ser adotar uma solução que pode ser mais complexa (ver primeiro *link*), ou ainda se está fazendo web algo que não deveria, esses problemas são mais relevantes.

Pegando esse exemplo em específico eu não separaria, porque se é para escrever no título do método, que é enorme, o que o método faz em vez de para que ele serve, então vejo pouca vantagem de separar essa implementação, se não for usado em outro lugar. É muito mais simples escrever logo ali no construtor o código que faz o que o título diz que faz. Dar bons nomes é ótimo para a legibilidade. Nomes ruins são tão ruins que não nomear ficar mais legível, e a única razão para um exemplo simples assim separar a implementação é dar um bom nome que dê semântica ao que está fazendo e não descrevendo o que será feito ali dentro.

É pior, porque ele considera que a classe é o campo único, um dia isso pode mudar e a tal validação passa nem fazer sentido. Não ajuda nada a legibilidade e a manutenção.

Não se apegue a detalhes que não ajudam o sistema ficar bom, não adote conceitos que não sabe usar, até aprender. Por exemplo, tanto faz se o modelo é anêmico ou não, ele será anêmico se isso for o melhor a ser adotado no caso concreto, ou não será se for necessário não ser. Desistir do modelo anêmico porque um "influencer" disse que é ruim, é não saber programar.

Tem que estudar profundamente tudo da computação e ver o que é melhor em cada situação entendendo as consequências de cada decisão, o carinha que disse que você deve ou não deve fazer não estará do seu lado fazendo o software e não terá consequências boas ou ruins se o seu software sair errado. Pegue todas informações possíveis sobre o assunto e tome uma decisão no caso concreto, não siga receitas de bolo.

Quando o programador não estuda toda computação antes de programar ele vira um [Sandoval Quaresma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q4ZnHDDJkU&list=PL16Uo5ODzY2Q_TfQBUvmb3HhUEyAF3nzj). Por isso dei alguns subsídios para estudar todo o processo e tomar uma boa decisão quando tiver o caso concreto, mas ainda precisa estudar muito mais que isso.

Uma última dica: só fará certo depois de muita experiência e muito erro. Erros que precisam ser reconhecidos por pessoas que programam bem. Se forem avaliados por pessoas que programam mal é o erro que treinará e é ele que fará para sempre. Se ninguém avaliar o que faz antes de ser experiente, todos os erros que não sabe que comete serão trinados e se solidificarão e se tornarão permanentes, por isso é importante escolher quem são suas referências.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).