# até que ponto o acoplamento entre classes é ruim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, engenharia-de-software, design-pattern

Estou criando um gerador de cupom base que vai ter 2 filhas, gerador de cupom especial e gerador de cupom normal. Também tenho um serviceCupom que vai gerenciar tudo e um controller que invoca os metodos de serviceCupom.

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost("normal")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Cupom?>> PostCupomComun(CupomNormalRequest cupomNormal) {
    var cupom = await _service.InsertCupomAsync(new GeradorCupomNormal(cupomNormal.DataDeValidade), cupomNormal.Value, cupomNormal.Amount);
    if(cupom == null ) 
       return BadRequest("Por um motivo desconhecido o cupom não foi criado");

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCupom", new {cupomCode = cupom.CupomCode}, cupom.CupomCode);      
        
}
```

Eu passo um gerador já instanciado pelo parametro de InsertCupomAsync(), esse espera uma interface IGeradorCupom

**CupomService**

```
public async Task<Cupom?> InsertCupomTesteAsync(IGeradorCupom gerador, decimal value, int amount)
{  
   var cupom = gerador.Gerar(value,  amount);
   await _repo.InsertCupomAsync(cupom);
   return cupom;   
}
```

Mas a minha duvida é a seguinte, com o controller tendo que conhecer como se cria um objeto Gerador de cupom temos um acoplamento. Seria esse acoplamento muito ruim ?

O codigo acima é uma *"melhora"* do codigo abaixo:

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost("normal")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Cupom?>> PostCupomComun(CupomNormalRequest cupomNormal) {
    var cupom = await _service.InsertCupomAsync(ECupomTypes.Normal,cupomNormal.Value,cupomNormal.Amount, cupomNormal.DataDeValidade);
    if(cupom == null ) 
       return BadRequest("Por um motivo desconhecido o cupom não foi criado");

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCupom", new {cupomCode = cupom.CupomCode}, cupom.CupomCode);      
}
```

**cupomService.cs**

```
public async Task<Cupom?> InsertCupomAsync(ECupomTypes typeCupom,decimal value, int amount, DateTime? dataValidade)
        { 
            if(typeCupom == ECupomTypes.Normal) 
            { 
                _geradorCupomNormal.AdicionarDataValidade(dataValidade);
                var cupom = _geradorCupomNormal.Gerar(value,  amount);
                await _repo.InsertCupomAsync(cupom);
                return cupom;
            }

            else if(typeCupom == ECupomTypes.Especial) {
                var cupom = _geradorCupomEspecial.Gerar(value, amount);
                await _repo.InsertCupomAsync(cupom);
                return cupom;
            }
            else 
                return null;
  
        }
```

Nesse ultimo exemplo, cupomService vai receber os geradores de cupom pelo construtor por injeção de dependencia. Mas em compensação vou ficar com varios if's. No primeiro exemplo eu  ainda conto com uma abstração então cupomService não vai ficar dependente de uma implementação, só o controller. Esse acoplamento seria muito ruim ?

Comment: Não respondendo a pergunta mas fazendo uma observação sobre o código, você está tendo de usar esses ifs dentro do método `InsertCupomAsync()` porque não está usando padrão de constructor conforme ao que precisa. Como sugestão de uma olhada no [Builder Pattern](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252765/como-e-quando-construir-um-objeto-em-estado-v%c3%a1lido#:~:text=O%20padr%C3%A3o%20de%20projeto%20Builder)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252765/como-e-quando-construir-um-objeto-em-estado-v%c3%a1lido). Apesar de considerar duplicada leva um +1, pois gostei de ler a pergunta e caso você ou a comunidade concorde que a resposta a sua pergunta esteja na pergunta que liguei como duplicada, bem votada ela fica disponível como acesso a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou considerar que a unica difereça entre o Cupom Comum e o Especial é a data de validade.

Você poderia ter um unico endpoint para a criação do Cupom, e utilizar a sujestão do [@Augosto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/565479/at%C3%A9-que-ponto-o-acoplamento-entre-classes-%C3%A9-ruim#comment999177_565479) de utilizar o [Builder Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/pt-br/design-patterns/builder) para criação do objeto Cupom.

Desta forma:

- Você pode deixar seu controller limpo, só passando os dados da request para o service;
- No builder do cupom, ficaria toda a logica de como criar um cupom, incluindo validações de que se for um cupom especial deve-se informar uma data de validade;
- Seu service, utilizaria os dados da request para montar o cupom utilizando o builder e por fim registra-lo;