# Instanciar um objeto na mesma classe do construtor é "deselegante"?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, objetos, construtor

É sempre visto como uma boa prática de programação se criar uma classe para o objeto, onde temos o construtor e fazemos os métodos e uma outra classe onde instanciamos vários objetos da classe criada anteriormente.

Entretanto, eu gostaria de saber se é considerado deselegante ou um mal estilo você criar os objetos na mesma classe onde criou os métodos e construtores.

Por exemplo, se temos um programa muito simples, como esse abaixo:

```
public class Main {
    private int var1, var2, soma;

    public Main(int var1, int var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public void sum(){
        soma = var1 + var2;
        System.out.println("resultado = " + soma);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Main m = new Main(2,5);
        m.sum();
   }
}
```

Isso pode ser considerada uma má prática?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> É sempre visto como uma boa prática de programação se criar uma classe para o objeto

Isso nada tem a ver com boa prática, ou você faz porque precisa, ou não faz.

Fora isso o resto do parágrafo não parece ser relevante ou apenas "chove no molhado", nem sei se o entendi.

A classe como um todo não é muito boa. Provavelmente porque é um exemplo artificial. Exemplos artificias funcionam para denotar um mecanismo específico da linguagem ou algoritmo específico que não importa muito o código em si, mas para exemplificar estilo, prática, elegância, tem que se atentar a cada detalhe, um espaço em branco pode mudar tudo. Falando em estilo, a classe não faz sentido e não deveria ser escrita assim.

Imagino que o foco da pergunta é se é bom colocar esse método `main()` que deve ser o ponto de entrada da aplicação. Para um exercício, uma demonstração rápida, tudo é válido, o código será jogado fora em seguida. Para um código em produção, para algo que será dada manutenção, não faz sentido. Cada classe deve ter uma só responsabilidade. Se ele cuida do objeto não deve ser o ponto de entrada da aplicação.

Se este método fosse um [*factory method*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) aí faria sentido, você criaria o objeto em um método estático na classe, e faria sentido estar dentro dela porque é responsabilidade dela facilitar a criação dos seus objetos.

Percebeu que contexto é muito importante para saber o que é elegante?