# Usando métodos estáticos de fábrica ao invés de construtores

Tags: java, design-pattern, construtor, singleton, flyweight

Andei pesquisando a respeito desse assunto depois que li no livro do Joshua Block, Java Efetivo, Item 1, sobre o uso de métodos estáticos de fábrica ao invés de constutores. Lá no texto ele defende o uso, sempre que possíveis e cita, entre outras justificativas, a possibilidade de implementar os padrões *Singleton* ou *Flyweight*. Cita também o caso da Classe `Boolean`, que usa sabiamente o *Flyweight* através do método `valueOf(boolean)`:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

A minha pergunta é: Eu entendo as vantagens de se usar esses patterns, mas não seria possível implementá-los no próprio construtor? O uso deles não justifica, por si só, a criação de um método estático de fábrica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema do construtor é que ele faz alocação de memória para o objeto você querendo ou não, com o [método fábrica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) você decide o que fazer.

No caso do `Boolean` ele tem 2 objetos alocados e se precisar usar milhares de vezes só esses dois serão alocados. Com o construtor criará milhares de objetos mesmo que possa usar os 2 objetos já existentes esses objetos serão criados (se não mudou nada até onde eu vi, são 20 bytes cada um, fora o ponteiro para referenciá-lo que hoje em dia é sempre 8 bytes).

Um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) no fundo faz duas coisas: alocação de memória e inicialização, se ele só fizesse o segundo então daria para fazer isto sem a fábrica.

Em Java é assim, outras linguagens podem permitir.

Tem desvantagem também fazer assim, afinal ele esconde uma possível alocação de memória. "Programador *enterprise*" em geral não liga muito pra isso e por essa razão que fazem aplicação que consomem muitos recursos e depois culpam o coitado do Java (não é culpa da linguagem é culpa da cultura dos programadores que a usam). Outros programadores costumam se preocupar com isso e deixar explícito ajuda pensar se fará aquilo ou não.

Algumas pessoas defendem que nem deveria existir construtores puros e só Fabric Methods. Faz algum sentido, mas eu queria uma forma de mostrar se vai alocar ou não.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E como lidar com a questão da injeção de dependência quando se torna o construtor privado? É possível usar DI quando se usa essa estratégia de construção de instâncias?

Comment: É outra coisa, mas guarda alguma semelhança.