# Para que serve usar Option como tipo no argumento de uma função?

Tags: rust

Eu estou tentando usar uma função que tem como argumento uma variável do tipo `Option`.

Um exemplo sem Option:

```rust
fn main() {
    next10(9);
}

fn next10(n: i32) {
    for i in n..n+10 {
        println!("{}", i)
    }
}
```

Um exemplo com Option:

```rust
fn main() {
    next10(Some(9));
}

fn next10(n: Option<isize>) {
    let k = n.unwrap();
    for i in k..k+10 {
        println!("{}", i)
    }
}
```

O que me incomodou aqui é ter que usar o `Some` toda vez que for usar a função que tem um tipo `Option` como argumento.

Para que isso é usado? Existe uma forma mais "limpa" (sem o `Some`) de usar funções desse tipo?

Comment: Nesse caso eu confesso que não consegui ver justificativa para uso, ainda mais usando o `unwrap`... De onde veio esse exemplo?

Comment: Eu tentei criar um exemplo para replicar o problema que tive usando a implementação `head` do struct `DataFrame` do polars: https://docs.rs/polars/0.12.1/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.head

Comment: Eu tentei passar o número inteiro e estava dando erro. Aí vi que consigo usando `Some`, o que me pareceu muito cumbersome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não gostou e não precisa, não use esta forma. Quase sempre não precisa. Mas se usar tem que pagar o preço que o mecanismo cobra. Tudo é *tradeoff* em computação.

Quando você cria um tipo assim precisa inicializar o valor dele de alguma forma, e Rust tudo precisa ser explícito, além de não ter construtor da forma como conhecemos em outras linguagens, então temos [métodos fábrica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) para criar um valor válido, portanto de alguma forma você tem que dizer o tipo que está criando, até para a inferência funcionar quando isso é usado. O `Some()` é esse método que recebe um valor padrão de outro tipo e cria um objeto do tipo `Option`.

Até tem como não fazer isso que é você já ter um objeto `Option` pronto para udo vindo de algum lugar. E normalmente é nesses casos que deveria ter uma parâmetro recebendo `Option`.

Se conhece outras linguagens deve entender o conceito de tipos anuláveis. Algumas de um jeito, outras de outro, mas a ideia geral é que um tipo pode ter um valor natural daquele objeto ou um valor nulo.

Este padrão é considerado o [erro de 1 bilhão de dólares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions), e linguagens mais modernas evitam isso não permitindo o valor nulo.

Mas como resolver a questão quando um valor inválido para o objeto é necessário para a semântica do problema? Ou seja, como resolver quando um valor pode existir ou não de acordo com a definição do domínio que está trabalhando?

Simples, use um tipo especial que tenha o valor ou um indicador que não tem valor. Este tipo é o `Option`.

Se você recebe um objeto que pode ser um `Option` quase sempre deve usar um *pattern matching* para resolver oque fazer quando tem um valor ou quando não tem. Eventualmente outra forma de seleção sobre o `Some` e o `None` pode resolver.

Simplesmente deixar dar erro não parece uma ideia muito correta (mas sempre há exceções), e parece abuse do uso de pânico (que é o equivalente ao abuso de exceções de outras linguagens). Em geral o mais correto geralmente seria retornar um `Result` indicando o erro. Mas o mais correto ainda seria não receber o `Option` neste caso porque você não tem o que fazer se vier um dado inválido. É o que eu sempre falo para não capturar exceções quando você não pode fazer nada útil.

Este é um caso claro do uso do mecanismo só para demonstrá-lo em ação, não para mostrar a utilidade dele. Não houve ganho neste código colocar esse parâmetro.

Um bom uso poderia ser se o valor `None` obrigaria realizar algo, como gerar um `Result`, já falado, mandar uma mensagem para o usuário (se isto for pertinente, for um método de UI), gerar um *log*, executar uma ação específica por não ter um valor válido, ou seja, o valor inválido pode ser tratado de forma útil. Ignorar o `None` indica que este objeto não deveria ser recebido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Conceptual.md).