# Por que um método static implementado não pode fazer referência a um método abstract?

Tags: javascript, typescript, classes, característica-linguagem, this

Em uma classe abstrata *factory* (`VehicleFactory`), estou tentando criar um método `static getVehicle` que implementa o método `abstract createVehicle` como o *factory* dos objetos a serem instanciados pelas subclasses de `VehicleFactory`. O método `abstract createVehicle` será implementado somente nestas subclasses.

A ideia é não precisar instanciar as subclasses de `VehicleFactory` para criar os objetos como, por exemplo, o `CarFactory` para criar objetos `Car`, porém o Lint tá dizendo que o método `abstract createVehicle` da `VehicleFactory` não existe, mas isso ocorre somente na implementação da função `static getVehicle`, o que já não acontece quando referencia o `abstract createVehicle` no método `pickUp()` do `VehicleFactory` que é *public*, porque um método *static* implementado não pode fazer referência a um método abstrato?

> error: Property 'createVehicle' does not exist on type 'typeof VehicleFactory'.

```
export abstract class Vehicle {
  constructor(protected name: string) {}

  pickUp(customerName: string): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} is going to take ${customerName}`);
  }

  stop(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} stopped.`);
  }
}
```

```
import { Vehicle } from '../interfaces/vehicle';

export abstract class VehicleFactory {
  protected abstract createVehicle(vehicleName: string): Vehicle;

  pickUp(customerName: string, vehicleName: string): Vehicle {
    const car = this.createVehicle(vehicleName);
    car.pickUp(customerName);
    return car;
  }

  static getVehicle(vehicleName: string): Vehicle {
    return this.createVehicle(vehicleName);
  }
}
```

```
import { Car } from '../classes/Car';
import { Vehicle } from '../interfaces/vehicle';
import { VehicleFactory } from './VehicleFactory';

export class CarFactory extends VehicleFactory {
  protected createVehicle(vehicleName: string): Vehicle {
    return new Car(vehicleName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema na verdade é o `this`. Este o que?

O método estático faz parte da [classe e não do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101), ele existe sem ter um objeto, então o `this` se refere a qual objeto? Nenhum, isso não pode ser usado. O `this` só pode ser usado em métodos de instância. O `this` é um parâmetro oculto, é algo que recebe um objeto nele, um método estático não tem esse parâmetro oculto. Ele não pode ser usado.

Ok, esta é a explicação do problema, porém não é a solução dele. Esse método, nessa forma não faz sentido, talvez outras coisas também não façam sentido, mas não posso falar sem entender todo contexto. Esse método inclusive viola o [padrão de Factory](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101), então a solução é só retirá-lo, até porque não vi motivo para ele existir.

Não funcionou por um problema  que nem deveria acontecer. Para estar certo é só não fazer nada disso.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: É possível chegar a essa solução retornando a instância de um genérico extendido como VehicleFactory na static getVehicle ainda usando ela como método estático?

Comment: Não sei o que é "instância de um genérico extendido"., mas parece que não.

Comment: https://blog.rsuter.com/how-to-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-typescript/ uma comparação com o c# do que eu quis dizer, esse é um caso que não iria precisar do this dentro da estática

Comment: É o que eu falei, esse método não faz sentido, ele não deveria existir, ele sequer tem função. Se aprendeu isso em algum lugar, jogue fora o material, se não aprendeu assim, não faça assim.

Answer (score 3):

Esse problema tem mais a ver com JavaScript do que com o TypeScript.

Embora JavaScript não tenha classes abstratas, quando o TypeScript for compilado e gerar código JavaScript, classes marcadas com `abstract` serão “transpiladas” para classes “normais”.

O `static`, contudo, [está presente no JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) e seu comportamento será mantido no código gerado.

De acordo com a documentação:

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.

Em tradução livre:

> A palavra chave `static` define um método estático ou propriedade para uma classe. **Métodos estáticos ou propriedades estáticas não podem ser chamados em instâncias da classe.** Devem ser chamados na própria classe.

A frase destacada é essencial para entender o problema. Basicamente, quando você define algo como `static`, não faz sentido utilizar o `this` para acessá-lo. Isso porque, nesse contexto, o `this` refere-se às instâncias da classe.

Como métodos estáticos *não* se associam à instância, mas sim à classe, não é certo utilizar `this` para acessá-los. Nesse caso, você terá `undefined` uma vez que métodos estáticos não chegam sequer a ser definidos nas instâncias.

Você deve, então, acessar qualificando diretamente pelo nome da classe. Um exemplo mais simples:

```js
class MyClass {
  // Método estático que se associa à própria classe, e não às instâncias:
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('staticMethod called!');
  }
  
  instanceMethod() {
    console.log('instanceMethod called');
    
    // Veja que para chamar, não devemos utilizar o `this`, mas sim o próprio nome da classe:
    MyClass.staticMethod();
    
    // Veja que `staticMethod` não é definido na instância:
    console.log('staticMethod' in this); //=> false
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
instance.instanceMethod();
```

Não deixe de ler a [documentação sobre `static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). E sobre [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).