# Design Patterns, Estou com algumas dúvidas em relação ao Factory Method em C#

Tags: c#, design-pattern

Estou enfrentando algumas dúvidas relacionadas aos Design Patterns, em especial no Factory Method. Gostaria de saber mais sobre as circunstâncias para aplicar ou evitar esse padrão. Existe algum guia prático ou dicas que destacam em quais cenários o Factory Method se sobressai em comparação com outras abordagens de criação de objetos? Quais são as vantagens concretas ao utilizar esse padrão em situações específicas? Apesar de reconhecer sua aplicabilidade em diversas linguagens, gostaria de entender como ele se destaca, especialmente em ambientes C#.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.